# Рисует ли браузер то, что находится за областью видимости SVG холста?

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, svg

Обращаюсь к тем кто уже сталкивался. 
Вопрос такой:

Есть ли смысл кластеризовывать svg на квадратные области (сетку) с ссылками на объекты в них для фильтрации и последующего показа только элементов попадающих в область видимости (`display: none/block;`)?

Или браузеры умеют сами делать что-то подобное?

Спасибо!

Comment: Есть предположение, что врядли - браузеры не настолько тупые, и экономят производительность где могут. А если даже сейчас вдруг кто-то не может: через полгода сможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Область видимости называется Viewport она задается путем объявления размеров основного дескриптора:

```
<svg width="500px" height="300px"></svg>
```

Официальных данных по рендерингу вне области видимости я не нашел, но [частные эмпирические изыскания](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516237/are-svg-images-harder-to-render-for-a-browser-than-bitmaps) (путем профайлинга) подтверждают, что использование *display: none* вне зоны видимости позволяет существенно снизить количество использующихся ресурсов.