# масштабирование SVG элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, анимация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать формулу(или указать параметры), для правильного масштабирования элементов SVG. Приведу пример

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var $allFigures = $('#figures'),
    $figure = $('.figure'),
    $circle = $('circle'),
    $rect = $('rect'),
    $polygon = $('polygon'),
    attrBox = $allFigures.attr('viewBox'),
    initialWidth,
    initialHeight,
    initialX,
    initialY;

  console.log($figure.length + " = $figure count")

  $circle.click(function() {
    var R = $(this).attr("r");
    $(this).attr({
      "r": R * 2
    });
  })

  $rect.click(function() {
    initialX = $(this).attr("x");
    initialY = $(this).attr("y");
    initialWidth = $(this).attr("width");
    initialHeight = $(this).attr("height");

    $(this).attr({
      "x": initialX / 2,
      "y": initialY / 2,
      "width": initialWidth * 2,
      "height": initialHeight * 2
    });
  })

  $figure.on("click", $figure, function() {
    $(this).css({
      "fill": "#0f0"
    });
  })

}
```

```css
/*.figure:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="figures" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 400;" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect x="386" y="138.5" class="figure" fill="#A21E22" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="185" height="123"/>
  <circle class="figure" fill="#4CA146" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="118" cy="200" r="48"/>
  <polygon class="figure" fill="#FEE33A" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="287,123.2 304.3,176.3 360.1,176.3 314.9,209.1 332.2,262.2 287,229.3 241.8,262.2 
    259.1,209.1 213.9,176.3 269.7,176.3 "/>
</svg>
```

Как произвести постепенное масштабирование полигонального объекта `SVG`?  Из-за того что в SVG есть область видимости `viewBox`, я так понимаю, что единственный способ здесь  пересчитывать точки нахождения  `points` для объекта? Или есть ещё какой-нибудь метод равномерного масштабирования объекта?

Answer (score 4):

Метод есть и не нужно самому пересчитывать координаты фигур. Это за вас сделает
интерпретатор SVG. Смотрите, к вашему файлу я добавлю только одну строчку анимации viewBox. И будет плавное увеличение и уменьшение размера фигур.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="figures" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 400;" xml:space="preserve">
 <rect  x="386" y="138.5" class="figure" fill="#A21E22" stroke="#000"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="185" height="123"/>
 <circle  class="figure" fill="#4CA146" stroke="#000"  stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="118" cy="200" r="48"/>
 <polygon  class="figure" fill="#FEE33A" stroke="#000"  stroke-miterlimit="10" points="287,123.2 304.3,176.3 360.1,176.3 314.9,209.1 332.2,262.2 287,229.3 241.8,262.2 
 259.1,209.1 213.9,176.3 269.7,176.3 "/>
   <animate  attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "0s" dur = "10s" values = "0 0 600 400;-300 -200 1200 800;0 0 600 400" 
  fill = "freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </svg>
```

Увеличение 3 и 4-го атрибута `viewBox` уменьшает масштаб, а изменение первых двух атрибутов viewBox удерживают фигуру на месте.
 [подробнее здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615562/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-viewport-%D0%B8-viewbox)

Хотите начать анимацию по клику? добавляем `begin = "svg2.click"`, где svg2 идентификатор всего полотна.

```html
<svg id="svg2"  version="1.1" id="figures" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 400;" xml:space="preserve">
 <rect  x="386" y="138.5" class="figure" fill="#A21E22" stroke="#000"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="185" height="123"/>
 <circle  class="figure" fill="#4CA146" stroke="#000"  stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="118" cy="200" r="48"/>
 <polygon  class="figure" fill="#FEE33A" stroke="#000"  stroke-miterlimit="10" points="287,123.2 304.3,176.3 360.1,176.3 314.9,209.1 332.2,262.2 287,229.3 241.8,262.2 
 259.1,209.1 213.9,176.3 269.7,176.3 "/>
   <animate  attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "svg2.click" dur = "10s" values = "0 0 600 400;-300 -200 1200 800;0 0 600 400" 
  fill = "freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </svg>
```

Окружность можно масштабировать увеличением, уменьшением радиуса, не трогая `cx` и `cy`

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="figures" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="border:1px solid red;" >
  <circle  class="figure" fill="#4CA146" stroke="#000"   cx="118" cy="200" r="48">
   <animate  attributeName = "r" begin = "0" dur = "10s" values = "48;5;48" 
  fill = "freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </circle>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это конечно всё замечательно, но как проделывать анимацию только над одни элементом, при этом другие элементы в процесс масштабиравания что бы не входили? К примеру для моего полигонального объекта(звезды) необходимо увеличить масштаб по клику в 2 раза, но при этом другие объекты не должны менять свои размеры. Да и сразу же  задам вопрос на счет перекрытия, ведь если слой который будет анимироватся находиться ПОД элементом соседом, то он будет перекрываться?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Создайте, пожалуйста  новый вопрос, надеюсь, что смогу помочь. Ведь в этом вопросе речь шла о плавном изменении координат , и ни слова не было о раздельном масштабировании фигур.

Comment: Как вариант использовать transform scale .

Answer (score 3):

Коли речь зашла о раздельном масштабировании каждой из фигур - можно опробовать и такой вариант:

```css
p {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #929292;
}

#figura,
#figures {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #2cc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>SVG-масштабирование - клик по фигуркам внизу</p>
<svg version="1.1" id="figura" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <symbol id="figur" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" > 
    <polygon id="star" points="100,0 40,180 195,70 5,70 160,180" 
    style="fill-rule: nonzero; fill: #00BD00; cursor: pointer; stroke: none;" /> 
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#figur" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"/>
  <animate id="star" attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "star.click" dur = "5s" values = "0 0 200 200;-900 -900 2000 2000;0 0 200 200" fill = "freeze" repeatCount="2"/> <!-- indefinite -->
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" id="figures" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" y="50%">
    <stop class="stop-1" offset="0%" stop-color="#becccc"/>
    <stop class="stop-2" offset="75%" stop-color="#929292"/>
    <stop class="stop-3" offset="100%" stop-color="#becccc"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle  class="figure" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="url(#grad)" stroke="#000" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <animate  attributeName="r" begin="click" dur="5s" values="100;1;100" fill="freeze" repeatCount="2"/> <!-- indefinite -->
  </circle> 
</svg>
```

Анимация иных фигур, вписанных между `<symbol>...</symbol>` аналогична анимации звезды.

Comment: хороший ответ (+) Немного есть лишних стилей, в частности stroke-width="1px", так как это значение по умолчанию

Comment: - Исправил, спасибо за замечание... )))