# SVG use xlink не работает в Firefox баг или где то ошибка?

Tags: svg, firefox

На сайте подгружается отдельный HTML файл, в котором объявлен один большой SVG код.
**Пример:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="icon-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 129.19 245.66"><title>icon-arrow-left</title>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#b89d67" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="9" d="M126.01 242.48L6.36 122.83 126.01 3.18"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 129.19 245.66">
    <title>icon-arrow-right</title>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#b89d67" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="9" d="M3.18 3.18l119.65 119.65L3.18 242.48" data-name="Layer 1"/>
</symbol></svg>
```

В указанных местах использую обычный вызов.
**Пример:**

```
<svg class="logo">
    <use xlink:href="#logo"></use>
</svg>
```

В Chrome и IE все работает, но в Firefox иконки отображаются исключительно только на главной страницы сайта на внутренних иконки не отображаются, вычитал что проблема в теге *base*. Решил проверить, если тег *base* убрать, то все корректно работает и на внутренних страницах сайта.
В теге *base* указана ссылка на главную страницу сайта - всегда.
Это *особенность* Firefox или где то допущена ошибка?

Comment: Включите строку xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" В этой строке должно быть впереди http:// www, которые не показываются.

Comment: Дело не в этом, проверял.

Comment: @Solunski.D Если Вас устраивает ответ, отметьте пожалуйста его, как решение вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox любит определенность. Поэтому действительно необходимо полное заполнение шапки файла SVG. Кроме того он считает все пропорции исходя из заданных величин Viewport и viewBox. У вас они не заданы в шапке файла, но задан вторичный viewBox тега symbol. А он считается в зависимости от первичного viewBox в шапке, которого нет. Поэтому, если запустить ваш файл в чистом виде никуда не подключая, ничего не видно. В вашем проекте видимо накладываются какие-то дополнительные условия и в результате появляется исчезающий эффект, то видно то невидно.  Предлагаю свой вариант файла, в котором по крайне мере всегда будут видны ваши скобочки.

```html
<div class="row">
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="600" height="245" viewBox="0 0 1200 490">
   
   <symbol id="icon-arrow-left">
     <path fill="none" stroke="#b89d67" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="9" d="M126.01 242.48L6.36 122.83 126.01 3.18"/>
   </symbol> 

     <symbol id="icon-arrow-right">
     <path fill="none" stroke="#b89d67" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="9" d="M3.18 3.18l119.65 119.65L3.18 242.48" />
     </symbol>

     <use x="0" xlink:href="#icon-arrow-left" />
  <use x="850" xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right" />
  
</svg>
<div>
```

Координатами `x` и `y` можно регулировать положение скобочек.
Цифрами во viewport и viewBox можно регулировать масштаб изображения.
[подробнее здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615562/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-viewport-%D0%B8-viewbox/618156#618156). 
Как подключать файл в HTML страничку [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047).