# SVG: удалить отступы по краям автоматически

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

Столкнулся с проблемой при верстке сайта. У меня есть ряд иконок SVG, которые выглядят примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что вокруг самого изображения есть отступы до краев. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы этих отступов не было, потому что с ними каждую иконку при размещении в элементе приходится подгонять по размеру и позиционированию в css.

Я знаю, как убрать эти отступы с помощью Inkscape. Но это ручная работа, а иконок много.

Есть ли какая-то утилита, которая может убрать эти отступы автоматически? Предпочтительно под Linux (node, python подойдет).

Пример SVG: [gist](https://gist.github.com/cronfy/f87891a355c6db8432e2c6dbe47b02d7)

Comment: Тут не всё так просто...

Comment: @cronfy Поделитесь, пожалуйста, как продвигается дело с автоматизацией обработки иконок. Я думаю многим будет интересно

Comment: @Alexandr_T спасибо за вопрос! :) сподвиг меня на то, чтобы добить эту задачу. У меня получилось написать скрипт с использованием PhanomJS. Я добавил ответ, а также сделал репозиторий на github: https://github.com/cronfy/svg-padding-remover

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Короткий ответ

[Вот такой скрипт](https://github.com/cronfy/svg-padding-remover).

Он требует PhantomJS и работает следующим образом:

```
phantomjs svg-padding-remover.js path/to/image.svg > new.svg
```

### Длинный ответ

Можно использовать PhantomJS для эмуляции браузера в командной строке. Соответственно, при этом для манипуляций с SVG доступны [все возможные браузерные методы](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html) (читающим это просьба дать в комментариях ссылку получше).

Я использовал [ответ Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627736/200260) (спасибо за идею!), чтобы написать такой скрипт командной строки.

Если скрипт максимально упростить (убрать разбор аргументов командной строки, обработку ошибок), и оставить только сам принцип работы, получится вот это:

### remover.js

```
// здесь нужно указать путь до картинки
var fs = require('fs');
var url = 'file://' + fs.absolute('1.svg');

// открываем файл svg как документ
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function () {
    // Вызов нашей функции, которая будет выполнена
    // в контексте открытого документа.
    // Она изменит документ (svg) необходимым нам образом.
    page.evaluate(svgPaddingRemover);

    // вывод нового содержимого документа
    console.log(page.content);

    // выход
    phantom.exit();
});

// Функция, которая изменяет документ.
// В данном случае - корректирует viewBox, удаляет width и height.
var svgPaddingRemover = function () {
    var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    var svgall = svg.querySelectorAll("*");
    var l = Infinity, t = Infinity, r = -Infinity, b = -Infinity;

    for (i = 0; i < svgall.length; i++) {
        var elem = svgall[i];
        var bb = elem.getBBox();

        if (bb.width && bb.height) {
            l = Math.min(l, bb.x);
            t = Math.min(t, bb.y);
            r = Math.max(r, bb.x + bb.width);
            b = Math.max(b, bb.y + bb.height);
        }
    }

    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", l + ' ' + t + ' ' + (r - l) + ' ' + ' ' + (b - t));
    svg.removeAttribute("width");
    svg.removeAttribute("height");
};
```

Запуск скрипта:

```
phantomjs remover.js > cropped-image.svg
```

Comment: Но ведь наверняка в nodejs есть специализированные штуки для svg?

Comment: @cronfy я понял, что отступы убираются за счет увеличения размеров иконки. Не помешает в вашем проекте?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, так он это и хотел.

Comment: @Qwertiy наверняка, но я не нашел рабочих модулей npm, впрочем, я не очень в них разбираюсь. Если кто-то подскажет, какой модуль можно использовать, будет здорово, потому что тогда получится перевести скрипт на gulp.

Comment: @Alexandr_T изменение размера не должно вызвать проблем, потому что размер все равно явно задается в css.

Comment: @Qwertiy смотрите, нюанс такой. У `сronfy` иконки были разного масштаба и после обработки сохранится та же картина. Если в проекте родительский контейнер будет иметь одинаковые размеры, то иконки будут обрезаться

Comment: @Alexandr_T, нет, иконки масштабируются.

Comment: @Qwertiy если всё это заработает, цены нет вашему решению. А то мы всё по старинке , всё на коленке.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, они же векторные. Т. е. мы в том же (прописанном в css) размере показываем меньшую область (ну или большую, если там что-то в иконку не влазило).

Comment: @Qwertiy я это и имел ввиду, что придется работать индивидуально либо с каждой иконкой, либо с местом под неё в css. А вообще очень интересный вопрос и интересное решение ваше, Qwertiy

Comment: @Alexandr_T собственно, задача была обработать иконки ДО использования в проекте. Чтобы можно было вставлять их в контейнер и растягивать на всю ширину, а не подгонять по отступам. И нормально центрировать. Конечно, если уже подогнанные иконки обработать скриптом, отображение поедет, нужно после обработки подправить css и убрать ненужные более смещения.

Comment: @cronfy Наверное уже не будет больше ответов. Мне кажется, пора закрывать вопрос. Всё в ваших руках, по правилам сайта, какой ответ выберете лучшим, тот и отметьте, наверное в первую очередь Qwertiy или свой, не стесняйтесь:)

Answer (score 6):

Можно быстрее убрать отступы используя `viewport`и `viewBox`
Например есть такая иконка

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 96 96"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" >
    <g fill="#00BCD4">
        <rect x="37" y="18" width="6" height="24"/>
        <rect x="29" y="26" width="6" height="16"/>
        <rect x="21" y="22" width="6" height="20"/>
        <rect x="13" y="32" width="6" height="10"/>
        <rect x="5" y="28" width="6" height="14"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="#3F51B5">
        <circle cx="8" cy="16" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="16" cy="18" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="24" cy="11" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="32" cy="13" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="40" cy="9" r="3"/>
        <polygon points="39.1,7.2 31.8,10.9 23.5,8.8 15.5,15.8 8.5,14.1 7.5,17.9 16.5,20.2 24.5,13.2 32.2,15.1 40.9,10.8"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Красная рамка вокруг иконки - это область видимости `viewport`. Вот эти отступы и сохраняются при вставке в html. 
Изменяя атрибуты  `viewport`и `viewBox` можно убрать отступы.
В примере ниже сохраняется масштаб 1:1, но уменьшается область просмотра и отступы практически уменьшаются.

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" >
    <g fill="#00BCD4">
        <rect x="37" y="18" width="6" height="24"/>
        <rect x="29" y="26" width="6" height="16"/>
        <rect x="21" y="22" width="6" height="20"/>
        <rect x="13" y="32" width="6" height="10"/>
        <rect x="5" y="28" width="6" height="14"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="#3F51B5">
        <circle cx="8" cy="16" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="16" cy="18" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="24" cy="11" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="32" cy="13" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="40" cy="9" r="3"/>
        <polygon points="39.1,7.2 31.8,10.9 23.5,8.8 15.5,15.8 8.5,14.1 7.5,17.9 16.5,20.2 24.5,13.2 32.2,15.1 40.9,10.8"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Если надо просто подвинуть иконку внутри `viewport` можно воспользоваться первыми двумя атрибутами viewBox="12 0 48 48" -сдвиг влево.
Более подробно: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615562/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-viewport-%D0%B8-viewbox) и [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1204)
Если у вас иконки однотипные, то поэкспериментировав с атрибутами `viewport` `viewBox` на одной иконке, далее можно сделать авто-замену атрибутов всего пакета иконок, например в notepad++

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Иконки, к сожалению, не совсем однотипные. Поэтому простая автозамена не подойдет.

Comment: @cronfy В той иконке, что Вы указали в шапке поста, совсем надо убрать отступы? Кстати обратите внимание на строку в моих примерах - style="border: 1px solid crimson;" Вот она и выявляет отступы.

Comment: Это не автоматический вариант.

Comment: @Alexandr_T да, нужно убрать совсем, абсолютно. Чтобы получилось так: https://gist.github.com/cronfy/e3b1df6b31c709910a9fd4ce8aab45f0 (тут я руками подправил viewbox и удалил width и height, и на всякий случай background).

Comment: @cronfy отлично! всё правильно сделали - viewBox="128 56.4 581 468" , надо еще убирать всю служебную информацию, которую люстра оставляет `xml:space="preserve"` она ни на что не влияет, и групповые теги`<g>` в текущем варианте лишние

Comment: @Alexandr_T это да :) С удалением ненужного справится svgo. Вопрос в том, как автоматизировать пересчет viewport, svgo это делать не умеет. Вот Qwertiy в своем ответе предложил рабочий алгоритм, осталось придумать, как его перевести на nodejs, а я в серверном js не очень силен :(

Comment: @cronfy сейчас так много подборок векторных иконок, что можно избавиться от рутинной работы. Просто выбрать иконки с одинаковыми `viewBox` и минимальными отступами. Тем более, что для дальнейшего использования их в спрайтах лучше иметь одинаковые параметры   `viewBox` в тегах `<symbol>`

Answer (score 4):

Простейший вариант будет примерно таким:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
  var l = Infinity, t = Infinity, r = -Infinity, b = -Infinity;
  
  for (var elem of svg.querySelectorAll("*")) {
    var bb = elem.getBBox();
    if (bb.width && bb.height) {
      l = Math.min(l, bb.x);
      t = Math.min(t, bb.y);
      r = Math.max(r, bb.x + bb.width);
      b = Math.max(b, bb.y + bb.height);
    }
  }
  
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `${l} ${t} ${r-l} ${b-t}`);
  svg.removeAttribute("width");
  svg.removeAttribute("height");
});
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 10em;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="836.2px" height="581.1px" viewBox="0 0 836.2 581.1" enable-background="new 0 0 836.2 581.1" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <g>
   <path d="M440.4,119.9h-1c-6.7,0-12.1,5.4-12.1,12.1s5.4,12.1,12.1,12.1h1c6.7,0,12.1-5.4,12.1-12.1     C452.5,125.3,447.1,119.9,440.4,119.9z"/>
   <path d="M657.2,249.3c-4.7-4.7-12.4-4.7-17.1,0l-7.8,7.8l-7.8-7.8c-4.7-4.7-12.4-4.7-17.1,0c-4.7,4.7-4.7,12.4,0,17.1l7.8,7.8     l-7.8,7.8c-4.7,4.7-4.7,12.4,0,17.1c2.4,2.4,5.5,3.5,8.6,3.5c3.1,0,6.2-1.2,8.6-3.5l7.8-7.8l7.8,7.8c2.4,2.4,5.5,3.5,8.6,3.5     s6.2-1.2,8.6-3.5c4.7-4.7,4.7-12.4,0-17.1l-7.8-7.8l7.8-7.8C661.9,261.7,661.9,254,657.2,249.3z"/>
   <path d="M576,249.3c-4.7-4.7-12.4-4.7-17.1,0l-7.8,7.8l-7.8-7.8c-4.7-4.7-12.4-4.7-17.1,0c-4.7,4.7-4.7,12.4,0,17.1l7.8,7.8     l-7.8,7.8c-4.7,4.7-4.7,12.4,0,17.1c2.4,2.4,5.5,3.5,8.6,3.5s6.2-1.2,8.6-3.5l7.8-7.8l7.8,7.8c2.4,2.4,5.5,3.5,8.6,3.5     c3.1,0,6.2-1.2,8.6-3.5c4.7-4.7,4.7-12.4,0-17.1l-7.8-7.8l7.8-7.8C580.8,261.7,580.8,254,576,249.3z"/>
   <path d="M666.3,149.5H517.7v-41c0-16.7-7.7-32-21.1-41.9c-13.4-9.9-30.3-12.9-46.3-8c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2l-76.5,27h-64.1     l-76.5-27c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-16-4.9-32.8-1.9-46.3,8c-13.4,9.9-21.1,25.2-21.1,41.9v41.3c-20.9,2.6-37.2,20.4-37.2,42     v290.5c0,23.4,19,42.4,42.4,42.4h496.4c23.4,0,42.4-19,42.4-42.4V191.9C708.7,168.5,689.7,149.5,666.3,149.5z M387.4,144.1h15.1     c6.7,0,12.1-5.4,12.1-12.1s-5.4-12.1-12.1-12.1h-15.1v-13.4l70.1-24.7c8.5-2.5,17.4-0.9,24.6,4.4c7.2,5.3,11.3,13.5,11.3,22.5     v46.9c0,9-4.1,17.1-11.3,22.5c-7.1,5.3-16.1,6.9-24.6,4.4l-70.1-24.7V144.1L387.4,144.1z M373.2,178.2l41.7,14.7l27.1,46.9     l-13.8-2.4c-5.8-1-11.4,2.3-13.5,7.8l-4.8,13.2l-46.3-80.2L373.2,178.2L373.2,178.2z M319.2,110h44v44h-44V110z M321.9,178.2     l-46.3,80.2l-4.8-13.2c-2-5.5-7.7-8.8-13.5-7.8l-13.8,2.4l27.9-48.3l37.7-13.3L321.9,178.2L321.9,178.2z M189,108.5     c0-9,4.1-17.1,11.3-22.5c4.9-3.6,10.7-5.5,16.6-5.5c2.7,0,5.4,0.4,8,1.2l70.1,24.7v13.4h-53c-6.7,0-12.1,5.4-12.1,12.1     c0,6.7,5.4,12.1,12.1,12.1h53v13.4l-70.1,24.7c-8.5,2.5-17.4,0.9-24.6-4.4c-7.2-5.3-11.3-13.5-11.3-22.5V108.5L189,108.5z      M684.4,482.4c0,10-8.1,18.2-18.2,18.2H169.9c-10,0-18.2-8.1-18.2-18.2v-35.3h532.7L684.4,482.4L684.4,482.4z M684.4,422.9H151.8     v-60.5h532.7L684.4,422.9L684.4,422.9z M684.4,338.2H151.8V191.9c0-9.4,7.2-17.1,16.3-18.1c3.5,9.2,9.5,17.4,17.8,23.5     c9.2,6.8,19.9,10.3,30.9,10.3c5.1,0,10.3-0.8,15.3-2.3c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2l3.7-1.3l-26.7,46.3c-2.3,4.1-2.1,9.1,0.6,13     c2.7,3.9,7.4,5.8,12,5l29.4-5.1l10.2,28c1.6,4.4,5.6,7.5,10.3,7.9c0.4,0,0.7,0,1,0c4.3,0,8.3-2.3,10.5-6.1l59.1-102.5L402,292.9     c2.2,3.8,6.2,6.1,10.5,6.1c0.3,0,0.7,0,1,0c4.7-0.4,8.7-3.5,10.3-7.9l10.2-28l29.4,5.1c4.6,0.8,9.3-1.1,12-5     c2.7-3.9,2.9-8.9,0.6-13l-25.9-44.9c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1c5.1,1.5,10.2,2.3,15.3,2.3c11,0,21.8-3.5,30.9-10.3     c8.3-6.1,14.4-14.3,17.8-23.6h151.9c10,0,18.2,8.1,18.2,18.2L684.4,338.2L684.4,338.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
</p>

<button>Crop</button>
```

Comment: Отлично, алгоритм рабочий! А как можно это перевести под node?

Comment: @cronfy, ну как-то должно быть можно, но я не знаю :) В крайнем случае можно потыкать phantomjs.

Comment: Про phantomjs касательно генерации svg есть упоминание в этой статье: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/love-generating-svg-javascript-move-to-server/#phantomjs , кандидат на роль отправной точки.

Comment: Ну вот, вроде получилось. Посмотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать плагины для Gulp - gulp-imagemin и imagemin-svgo:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imageminSvgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: true}
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

Comment: Из документации: "remove viewBox attribute when possible (disabled by default)". Но ведь надо не удалить, а изменить.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло. Я добавил в вопрос пример иконки. После обработки вашим кодом в dest оказывается точно такая же иконка, только минифицированная и без viewbox. Но отступы никуда не деваются :(

Comment: @cronfy извините, не ту опцию дал. Вот список всех доступных опций, посмотрите - https://github.com/svg/svgo#what-it-can-do. Возможно, вам нужна removeDimensions.

Comment: @Vadizar я смотрел этот список перед тем как задать вопрос :) remove dimensions просто удалит width и height, а для достижения цели нужно еще подправить viewbox.