# SVG sprite. Неправильное позиционирование в хроме

Tags: svg, gulp, svg-спрайт

Создаю спрайт с помощью gulp (плагин gulp-svg-sprites). В Mozilla отображается нормально, в хроме открываю - всё сдвинуто. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если из конечного svg я генерирую png-спрайт (плагин gulp-svg2png), и подключаю его вместо svg, то во всех браузерах отображается нормально. т.е. я так понимаю это что-то связано именно из интерпретацией браузером.

Как исправить?

Пример моего спрайта после галпа есть [здесь](http://671349.agrariir.web.hosting-test.net/img/sprite.html) . При изменении размеров бегунком в хроме этот баг тоже можно увидеть (хорошо заметно при максимальном увеличении, на белых - когда инвертировать фон).

В мозиле всё нормально.

P.S. Обновил спрайт - установил, чтобы `viewBox` у всех элементов начинался с `"0 0`. не помогло.

Настройки gulp:

```
gulp.task('svg-sprites:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.theme.img_svg_src + '*.svg')
      .pipe(svgSprite())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.img_src + 'dict'))
      .pipe(filter(options.theme.img_src + 'dict/svg/*.svg')) 
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.img_src + 'dict'));
});
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто принял участие. Выбор победителя - задача сложная. Поэтому я решил сделать так:
 Каждый ответ получил от меня +1голос. 
Ответ cronfy был первым, который очень быстро решал мою проблему, поэтому я его отметил как правильный.
На момент окончания конкурса ответ Vadizar правильный и наиболее полный (по моему мнению), поэтому я его отметил как победителя...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Короткий ответ

Удалите атрибут `viewBox="0 0 41 2023"` из SVG. Впрочем, остальные viewBox тоже можете удалить. Можно сделать это автоматически с помощью [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) (плагин `removeViewBox`).

## Длинный ответ

Это похоже на баг `Chrome`, связанный с расчетом `background-size`, когда `background-size` по горизонтали не кратен ширине `viewBox` в SVG.

Смотрите, у вас `background-size` задается в em: `4.1em 202.3em` (sprite.css:5). А изменение размеров картинок задается через `font-size` от 2 до 14 px. Исходное значение `font-size` равно 10px, поэтому при открытии страницы размер фона  в пикселях получается 41x2023 px, как раз как viewBox в SVG. Можно прописать `background-size: 41px 2023px` и все останется по-прежнему.

Но если указать на пиксель меньше: `background-size: 40px 2023px`, мы увидим смещение по вертикали. Хотя, казалось бы, картинка должна стать просто немного уже.

Поэтому при изменении шрифта все едет. Если задать размер шрифта 11px, то ширина фона получится `4.1em * 11px = 45.1px`, а это не кратно 41 (ширина исходного viewBox). Следующее значение шрифта, при котором все показывается нормально - 20px: размер `background-size` по горизонтали становится 82px, что кратно 41.

Я точно не берусь описать все особенности этого бага (иногда он проявляется, иногда нет), но суть в том, что решение простое: удалите атрибут `viewBox="0 0 41 2023"` из SVG. Впрочем, остальные `viewBox` тоже можете удалить.

Можно сделать это автоматически с помощью [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) (плагин `removeViewBox`). Пример для `gulp`:

```
gulp.task('remove-viewbox', function() {
    var svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin');

    return gulp.src('src/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgmin({
            plugins: [ {removeViewBox: true} ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы наверное уже догадались, что в `Chrome` видите вместе с основной иконкой низ предыдущей иконки. 
Причин тут может быть много, но основных две:

1. У каждого браузера свои стили, поэтому лучше их сбросить отдельным файлом reset.css от Эрика Майера, либо применить [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), почитайте перевод статьи [здесь](https://webformyself.com/css-reset-ili-normalize/).
2. Вторая, основная причина - подбор иконок с разными пропорциями.

У одних `width="7" height="7" viewBox="0 0 7 7`, у других `viewBox="231 233 38 34` Видите, тут пришлось двигать иконку с помощью viewBox. И дальше, если посмотреть, запустите SVG файл спрайта локально, то увидите большие пробелы, это просто иконки не попадают в зону видимости.

Чтобы избежать таких рисков и непоняток, может быть проще найти SVG иконки с одинаковыми атрибутами. Таких подборок очень много в сети, где прямо они отсортированы по размерам 32x32; 64x64; 128x128...

Comment: На самом сайте используется normalize - ситуацию не меняет... поводу больших промежутков - это белые картинки и  при обычном просмотре их не видно (хотя если в инспекторе кода браузера установить background то всё видно). По поводу стандартных - многие картинки брал с разных библиотек, некоторые рисую сам (сайт дизайнерский, здесь выложена старая версия спрайта).... попробую сделать viewbox c нулевым углом для всех... подскажите как это можно сделать быстро... возможно есть какой-то плагин для нормализации svg?

Comment: @Alex а что значит с нулевым углом?  Для viewBox="0 0 32 32" Первые два нулевых параметра - это координаты по x / y

Comment: Для нормализации SVG есть плагины, но они уменьшают количество знаков после запятой и убирают служебный мусор после векторных редакторов, но viewBox не трогают.  Посмотрите утилитку, которую написал `Qwertiy` может подойдет вам http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627684/svg-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: а что это за утилита? где её можно посмотреть? увидел ссылку

Comment: @Alexandr_T normalize такая чушь. Она outline не убирает, а в этом случае так тем более ничего не решит.

Comment: @Alexandr_T а разные viewBox у всех будут. Можно конечно обрезать через плагины, как я указала в своем ответе, но думаю, что вариант с иконочным шрифтом будет предпочтительней.

Answer (score 4):

Я взял ваш спрайт и для наглядности немного отформатировал код, не изменяя  его сущности. Обратите внимание, что за вертикальные пробелы между иконками отвечают атрибуты `viewport`, которые обычно не указывают, так как по умолчанию они x="0" y="0" - это верхний левый угол. В вашем варианте для первой иконки y="0", для второй иконки - y="32", далее y="64" То есть вертикальное позиционирование исключительно зависит от этих параметров.

```html
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="41" height="2023" viewBox="0 0 41 2023" style="background:#000"><svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-facebook" y="0">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M19.8 6.5h5.5V.8h-5.5c-4.2 0-7.7 2.9-7.7 6.7v2.8H7.7V16h4.4v15.2h6.6V16h5.5l1.1-5.7h-6.6V7.5c0-.5.5-1 1.1-1z">
</path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-google" y="32">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M1.7 8.3c0 2.5.9 4.5 2.6 5.6 1.4.8 3.1 1 4 1h.5s-.3 1.7 1.1 3.5c-2.4 0-9.9.5-9.9 6.5 0 6.1 6.9 6.4 8.3 6.4h.5c.9 0 3.2-.1 5.3-1.1 2.7-1.2 4.1-3.6 4.1-6.7s-2.1-4.9-3.7-6.2c-.9-.8-1.8-1.5-1.8-2.2 0-.7.6-1.2 1.4-1.9 1.2-1 2.4-2.5 2.4-5.5 0-2.4-.3-4.2-2.4-5.4.2-.1 1-.2 1.4-.2 1.1-.2 2.7-.3 2.7-1.2V.8H10c-.1 0-8.3.2-8.3 7.5zM15 24c.2 2.4-2 4.2-5.2 4.5-3.3.2-6-1.2-6.1-3.7-.1-1.1.5-2.3 1.5-3.3S7.7 20 9.3 20h.6c2.9 0 4.9 1.7 5.1 4zM12.8 6.7c.8 2.8-.4 5.6-2.3 6.2h-.7c-1.8 0-3.5-1.7-4.2-4.2-.3-1.3-.2-2.5.1-3.7.4-1.1 1.1-1.9 2.1-2.1.2 0 .4-.1.6-.1 2.2 0 3.6.9 4.4 3.9zm13.9 5.8V7.2h-3.6v5.3h-5.3V16h5.3v5.3h3.6V16H32v-3.5h-5.3z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-instagram" y="64">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M16.5 15c0-.3-.2-.5-.5-.5-1.5 0-2.7 1.1-2.7 2.5 0 .3.2.5.5.5s.5-.2.5-.5c0-.8.8-1.5 1.6-1.5.4 0 .6-.2.6-.5zm3.8 2c0 2.2-2 4-4.3 4s-4.3-1.8-4.3-4 1.9-4 4.3-4 4.3 1.9 4.3 4zM3 26.1h26V24H3v2.1zM22.5 17c0-3.4-2.9-6.1-6.6-6.1S9.4 13.6 9.4 17s2.9 6.1 6.6 6.1 6.5-2.8 6.5-6.1zM5.3 6.9h6.6V4.8H5.3v2.1zM3 9.9h26v-4H15L13.9 8H3v1.9zm28.2-4v20.3c0 1.1-1 2.1-2.2 2.1H3c-1.2 0-2.2-.9-2.2-2.1V5.9c0-1.1 1-2.1 2.2-2.1h26c1.2 0 2.2.9 2.2 2.1z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-twitter" y="96">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M30.8 5.2c-1.1.6-2.3.9-3.5 1.1 1.2-.8 2.3-2.4 2.6-4-1.2.8-2.4 1.4-3.9 1.8-1.1-1.4-2.6-2.4-4.4-2.4-3.3 0-6 3.2-6 7.2 0 .6.1 1 .2 1.6-5-.3-9.5-3.1-12.5-7.5-.6 1-.9 2.4-.9 3.6 0 2.5 1 4.7 2.6 6-.9 0-1.9-.4-2.7-.8v.1c0 3.5 2.1 6.4 4.9 7.1-.6.2-1 .3-1.6.3-.4 0-.8-.1-1.1-.1.8 2.8 3 4.9 5.7 5-2.1 2-4.7 3.1-7.5 3.1-.6 0-.9 0-1.5-.1 2.6 2.1 5.9 3.2 9.3 3.2 11.2 0 17.2-11 17.2-20.5v-.8c1.2-1.2 2.2-2.4 3.1-3.9z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-vcontacte" y="128">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M22.6 15.1c1.1-1.5 1.9-3.4 1.9-5.6 0-4.7-3.6-8.6-8-8.6h-10V31h12c4.4 0 8-3.9 8-8.6 0-3.1-1.5-5.8-3.9-7.3zM12.5 5.3h3.2c1.8 0 3.2 2 3.2 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.2 4.3h-3.2V5.3zm4.9 21.4h-5v-8.6h5c1.9 0 3.3 2 3.3 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.3 4.3z"></path>
</svg>

 </svg>
```

Первый вариант решения - необходимо увеличить зазоры между иконками, то есть увеличить`Y` Внизу пример, как было, видите практически нет зазора между иконками. Во втором примере зазор увеличен на 8px; y=0;40;80;120

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="41" height="2023" viewBox="0 0 41 2023" style="background:#000"><svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-facebook" y="0">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M19.8 6.5h5.5V.8h-5.5c-4.2 0-7.7 2.9-7.7 6.7v2.8H7.7V16h4.4v15.2h6.6V16h5.5l1.1-5.7h-6.6V7.5c0-.5.5-1 1.1-1z">
</path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-google" y="40">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M1.7 8.3c0 2.5.9 4.5 2.6 5.6 1.4.8 3.1 1 4 1h.5s-.3 1.7 1.1 3.5c-2.4 0-9.9.5-9.9 6.5 0 6.1 6.9 6.4 8.3 6.4h.5c.9 0 3.2-.1 5.3-1.1 2.7-1.2 4.1-3.6 4.1-6.7s-2.1-4.9-3.7-6.2c-.9-.8-1.8-1.5-1.8-2.2 0-.7.6-1.2 1.4-1.9 1.2-1 2.4-2.5 2.4-5.5 0-2.4-.3-4.2-2.4-5.4.2-.1 1-.2 1.4-.2 1.1-.2 2.7-.3 2.7-1.2V.8H10c-.1 0-8.3.2-8.3 7.5zM15 24c.2 2.4-2 4.2-5.2 4.5-3.3.2-6-1.2-6.1-3.7-.1-1.1.5-2.3 1.5-3.3S7.7 20 9.3 20h.6c2.9 0 4.9 1.7 5.1 4zM12.8 6.7c.8 2.8-.4 5.6-2.3 6.2h-.7c-1.8 0-3.5-1.7-4.2-4.2-.3-1.3-.2-2.5.1-3.7.4-1.1 1.1-1.9 2.1-2.1.2 0 .4-.1.6-.1 2.2 0 3.6.9 4.4 3.9zm13.9 5.8V7.2h-3.6v5.3h-5.3V16h5.3v5.3h3.6V16H32v-3.5h-5.3z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-instagram" y="80">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M16.5 15c0-.3-.2-.5-.5-.5-1.5 0-2.7 1.1-2.7 2.5 0 .3.2.5.5.5s.5-.2.5-.5c0-.8.8-1.5 1.6-1.5.4 0 .6-.2.6-.5zm3.8 2c0 2.2-2 4-4.3 4s-4.3-1.8-4.3-4 1.9-4 4.3-4 4.3 1.9 4.3 4zM3 26.1h26V24H3v2.1zM22.5 17c0-3.4-2.9-6.1-6.6-6.1S9.4 13.6 9.4 17s2.9 6.1 6.6 6.1 6.5-2.8 6.5-6.1zM5.3 6.9h6.6V4.8H5.3v2.1zM3 9.9h26v-4H15L13.9 8H3v1.9zm28.2-4v20.3c0 1.1-1 2.1-2.2 2.1H3c-1.2 0-2.2-.9-2.2-2.1V5.9c0-1.1 1-2.1 2.2-2.1h26c1.2 0 2.2.9 2.2 2.1z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-twitter" y="120">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M30.8 5.2c-1.1.6-2.3.9-3.5 1.1 1.2-.8 2.3-2.4 2.6-4-1.2.8-2.4 1.4-3.9 1.8-1.1-1.4-2.6-2.4-4.4-2.4-3.3 0-6 3.2-6 7.2 0 .6.1 1 .2 1.6-5-.3-9.5-3.1-12.5-7.5-.6 1-.9 2.4-.9 3.6 0 2.5 1 4.7 2.6 6-.9 0-1.9-.4-2.7-.8v.1c0 3.5 2.1 6.4 4.9 7.1-.6.2-1 .3-1.6.3-.4 0-.8-.1-1.1-.1.8 2.8 3 4.9 5.7 5-2.1 2-4.7 3.1-7.5 3.1-.6 0-.9 0-1.5-.1 2.6 2.1 5.9 3.2 9.3 3.2 11.2 0 17.2-11 17.2-20.5v-.8c1.2-1.2 2.2-2.4 3.1-3.9z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" id="a-we-in-vcontacte" y="160">
<path fill="#FFF" d="M22.6 15.1c1.1-1.5 1.9-3.4 1.9-5.6 0-4.7-3.6-8.6-8-8.6h-10V31h12c4.4 0 8-3.9 8-8.6 0-3.1-1.5-5.8-3.9-7.3zM12.5 5.3h3.2c1.8 0 3.2 2 3.2 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.2 4.3h-3.2V5.3zm4.9 21.4h-5v-8.6h5c1.9 0 3.3 2 3.3 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.3 4.3z"></path>
</svg>


 </svg>
```

Учитывая, что в вашем варианте вы жестко привязаны к позиционированию иконок внутри спрайта и как выясняется это может приводить к непредсказуемым эффектам, можно предложить -

**Второй вариант**

сделать классический спрайт, используя теги `<symbol>` и  команды вызова `<use>` из спрайта.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200" style="background:#000; border:1px solid red;">

<symbol id="a-we-in-facebook"> viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M19.8 6.5h5.5V.8h-5.5c-4.2 0-7.7 2.9-7.7 6.7v2.8H7.7V16h4.4v15.2h6.6V16h5.5l1.1-5.7h-6.6V7.5c0-.5.5-1 1.1-1z">
</path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-google"> viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M1.7 8.3c0 2.5.9 4.5 2.6 5.6 1.4.8 3.1 1 4 1h.5s-.3 1.7 1.1 3.5c-2.4 0-9.9.5-9.9 6.5 0 6.1 6.9 6.4 8.3 6.4h.5c.9 0 3.2-.1 5.3-1.1 2.7-1.2 4.1-3.6 4.1-6.7s-2.1-4.9-3.7-6.2c-.9-.8-1.8-1.5-1.8-2.2 0-.7.6-1.2 1.4-1.9 1.2-1 2.4-2.5 2.4-5.5 0-2.4-.3-4.2-2.4-5.4.2-.1 1-.2 1.4-.2 1.1-.2 2.7-.3 2.7-1.2V.8H10c-.1 0-8.3.2-8.3 7.5zM15 24c.2 2.4-2 4.2-5.2 4.5-3.3.2-6-1.2-6.1-3.7-.1-1.1.5-2.3 1.5-3.3S7.7 20 9.3 20h.6c2.9 0 4.9 1.7 5.1 4zM12.8 6.7c.8 2.8-.4 5.6-2.3 6.2h-.7c-1.8 0-3.5-1.7-4.2-4.2-.3-1.3-.2-2.5.1-3.7.4-1.1 1.1-1.9 2.1-2.1.2 0 .4-.1.6-.1 2.2 0 3.6.9 4.4 3.9zm13.9 5.8V7.2h-3.6v5.3h-5.3V16h5.3v5.3h3.6V16H32v-3.5h-5.3z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-instagram" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M16.5 15c0-.3-.2-.5-.5-.5-1.5 0-2.7 1.1-2.7 2.5 0 .3.2.5.5.5s.5-.2.5-.5c0-.8.8-1.5 1.6-1.5.4 0 .6-.2.6-.5zm3.8 2c0 2.2-2 4-4.3 4s-4.3-1.8-4.3-4 1.9-4 4.3-4 4.3 1.9 4.3 4zM3 26.1h26V24H3v2.1zM22.5 17c0-3.4-2.9-6.1-6.6-6.1S9.4 13.6 9.4 17s2.9 6.1 6.6 6.1 6.5-2.8 6.5-6.1zM5.3 6.9h6.6V4.8H5.3v2.1zM3 9.9h26v-4H15L13.9 8H3v1.9zm28.2-4v20.3c0 1.1-1 2.1-2.2 2.1H3c-1.2 0-2.2-.9-2.2-2.1V5.9c0-1.1 1-2.1 2.2-2.1h26c1.2 0 2.2.9 2.2 2.1z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-twitter" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M30.8 5.2c-1.1.6-2.3.9-3.5 1.1 1.2-.8 2.3-2.4 2.6-4-1.2.8-2.4 1.4-3.9 1.8-1.1-1.4-2.6-2.4-4.4-2.4-3.3 0-6 3.2-6 7.2 0 .6.1 1 .2 1.6-5-.3-9.5-3.1-12.5-7.5-.6 1-.9 2.4-.9 3.6 0 2.5 1 4.7 2.6 6-.9 0-1.9-.4-2.7-.8v.1c0 3.5 2.1 6.4 4.9 7.1-.6.2-1 .3-1.6.3-.4 0-.8-.1-1.1-.1.8 2.8 3 4.9 5.7 5-2.1 2-4.7 3.1-7.5 3.1-.6 0-.9 0-1.5-.1 2.6 2.1 5.9 3.2 9.3 3.2 11.2 0 17.2-11 17.2-20.5v-.8c1.2-1.2 2.2-2.4 3.1-3.9z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-vcontacte" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M22.6 15.1c1.1-1.5 1.9-3.4 1.9-5.6 0-4.7-3.6-8.6-8-8.6h-10V31h12c4.4 0 8-3.9 8-8.6 0-3.1-1.5-5.8-3.9-7.3zM12.5 5.3h3.2c1.8 0 3.2 2 3.2 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.2 4.3h-3.2V5.3zm4.9 21.4h-5v-8.6h5c1.9 0 3.3 2 3.3 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.3 4.3z"></path>
</symbol>

<use y="50" xlink:href="#a-we-in-facebook"></use>
<use y="50"  x="50" xlink:href="#a-we-in-google"></use>
<use y="50"  x="100" xlink:href="#a-we-in-instagram"></use>
<use y="50"  x="150" xlink:href="#a-we-in-twitter"></use>
<use y="50"  x="200" xlink:href="#a-we-in-vcontacte"></use>

 </svg>
```

Такой вариант позволяет позиционировать иконки, используя x,y координаты в команде `<use>` и выглядит одинаково во всех браузерах.

Вариант с иконками в одном блоке, с минимальными отступами

```html
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="235" height="45" viewBox="0 0 235 45" style="background:#000; border:1px solid red;">

<symbol id="a-we-in-facebook"> viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M19.8 6.5h5.5V.8h-5.5c-4.2 0-7.7 2.9-7.7 6.7v2.8H7.7V16h4.4v15.2h6.6V16h5.5l1.1-5.7h-6.6V7.5c0-.5.5-1 1.1-1z">
</path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-google"> viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M1.7 8.3c0 2.5.9 4.5 2.6 5.6 1.4.8 3.1 1 4 1h.5s-.3 1.7 1.1 3.5c-2.4 0-9.9.5-9.9 6.5 0 6.1 6.9 6.4 8.3 6.4h.5c.9 0 3.2-.1 5.3-1.1 2.7-1.2 4.1-3.6 4.1-6.7s-2.1-4.9-3.7-6.2c-.9-.8-1.8-1.5-1.8-2.2 0-.7.6-1.2 1.4-1.9 1.2-1 2.4-2.5 2.4-5.5 0-2.4-.3-4.2-2.4-5.4.2-.1 1-.2 1.4-.2 1.1-.2 2.7-.3 2.7-1.2V.8H10c-.1 0-8.3.2-8.3 7.5zM15 24c.2 2.4-2 4.2-5.2 4.5-3.3.2-6-1.2-6.1-3.7-.1-1.1.5-2.3 1.5-3.3S7.7 20 9.3 20h.6c2.9 0 4.9 1.7 5.1 4zM12.8 6.7c.8 2.8-.4 5.6-2.3 6.2h-.7c-1.8 0-3.5-1.7-4.2-4.2-.3-1.3-.2-2.5.1-3.7.4-1.1 1.1-1.9 2.1-2.1.2 0 .4-.1.6-.1 2.2 0 3.6.9 4.4 3.9zm13.9 5.8V7.2h-3.6v5.3h-5.3V16h5.3v5.3h3.6V16H32v-3.5h-5.3z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-instagram" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M16.5 15c0-.3-.2-.5-.5-.5-1.5 0-2.7 1.1-2.7 2.5 0 .3.2.5.5.5s.5-.2.5-.5c0-.8.8-1.5 1.6-1.5.4 0 .6-.2.6-.5zm3.8 2c0 2.2-2 4-4.3 4s-4.3-1.8-4.3-4 1.9-4 4.3-4 4.3 1.9 4.3 4zM3 26.1h26V24H3v2.1zM22.5 17c0-3.4-2.9-6.1-6.6-6.1S9.4 13.6 9.4 17s2.9 6.1 6.6 6.1 6.5-2.8 6.5-6.1zM5.3 6.9h6.6V4.8H5.3v2.1zM3 9.9h26v-4H15L13.9 8H3v1.9zm28.2-4v20.3c0 1.1-1 2.1-2.2 2.1H3c-1.2 0-2.2-.9-2.2-2.1V5.9c0-1.1 1-2.1 2.2-2.1h26c1.2 0 2.2.9 2.2 2.1z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-twitter" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M30.8 5.2c-1.1.6-2.3.9-3.5 1.1 1.2-.8 2.3-2.4 2.6-4-1.2.8-2.4 1.4-3.9 1.8-1.1-1.4-2.6-2.4-4.4-2.4-3.3 0-6 3.2-6 7.2 0 .6.1 1 .2 1.6-5-.3-9.5-3.1-12.5-7.5-.6 1-.9 2.4-.9 3.6 0 2.5 1 4.7 2.6 6-.9 0-1.9-.4-2.7-.8v.1c0 3.5 2.1 6.4 4.9 7.1-.6.2-1 .3-1.6.3-.4 0-.8-.1-1.1-.1.8 2.8 3 4.9 5.7 5-2.1 2-4.7 3.1-7.5 3.1-.6 0-.9 0-1.5-.1 2.6 2.1 5.9 3.2 9.3 3.2 11.2 0 17.2-11 17.2-20.5v-.8c1.2-1.2 2.2-2.4 3.1-3.9z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-vcontacte" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path fill="#FFF" d="M22.6 15.1c1.1-1.5 1.9-3.4 1.9-5.6 0-4.7-3.6-8.6-8-8.6h-10V31h12c4.4 0 8-3.9 8-8.6 0-3.1-1.5-5.8-3.9-7.3zM12.5 5.3h3.2c1.8 0 3.2 2 3.2 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.2 4.3h-3.2V5.3zm4.9 21.4h-5v-8.6h5c1.9 0 3.3 2 3.3 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.3 4.3z"></path>
</symbol>

<use y="8" xlink:href="#a-we-in-facebook"></use>
<use y="8"  x="50" xlink:href="#a-we-in-google"></use>
<use y="8"  x="100" xlink:href="#a-we-in-instagram"></use>
<use y="8"  x="150" xlink:href="#a-we-in-twitter"></use>
<use y="8"  x="200" xlink:href="#a-we-in-vcontacte"></use>

 </svg>
```

Красная рамка - это граница SVG, только для просмотра, её можно убрать - `border:1px solid red;` я использовал её для настройки отступов.

**UPD** 23.02.2017

В дополнение блок SVG социальных иконок с рабочими ссылками на соцсети. Работоспособность проверена в: chrome, FF, Opera, Yandex

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="235" height="45" viewBox="0 0 235 45" style="background:black; ">
<style>
svg path{
fill:inherit;
}
#a-we-in-facebook,
#a-we-in-google,
#a-we-in-instagram,
#a-we-in-twitter,
#a-we-in-vcontacte
{
fill:inherit;
}
a:link
{
fill:white;
}
 a:focus,
a:active,
a:hover {
 
 fill:orange;
  }

</style>
<symbol id="a-we-in-facebook"> viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" >
<path  d="M19.8 6.5h5.5V.8h-5.5c-4.2 0-7.7 2.9-7.7 6.7v2.8H7.7V16h4.4v15.2h6.6V16h5.5l1.1-5.7h-6.6V7.5c0-.5.5-1 1.1-1z">
</path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-google"> viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path  d="M1.7 8.3c0 2.5.9 4.5 2.6 5.6 1.4.8 3.1 1 4 1h.5s-.3 1.7 1.1 3.5c-2.4 0-9.9.5-9.9 6.5 0 6.1 6.9 6.4 8.3 6.4h.5c.9 0 3.2-.1 5.3-1.1 2.7-1.2 4.1-3.6 4.1-6.7s-2.1-4.9-3.7-6.2c-.9-.8-1.8-1.5-1.8-2.2 0-.7.6-1.2 1.4-1.9 1.2-1 2.4-2.5 2.4-5.5 0-2.4-.3-4.2-2.4-5.4.2-.1 1-.2 1.4-.2 1.1-.2 2.7-.3 2.7-1.2V.8H10c-.1 0-8.3.2-8.3 7.5zM15 24c.2 2.4-2 4.2-5.2 4.5-3.3.2-6-1.2-6.1-3.7-.1-1.1.5-2.3 1.5-3.3S7.7 20 9.3 20h.6c2.9 0 4.9 1.7 5.1 4zM12.8 6.7c.8 2.8-.4 5.6-2.3 6.2h-.7c-1.8 0-3.5-1.7-4.2-4.2-.3-1.3-.2-2.5.1-3.7.4-1.1 1.1-1.9 2.1-2.1.2 0 .4-.1.6-.1 2.2 0 3.6.9 4.4 3.9zm13.9 5.8V7.2h-3.6v5.3h-5.3V16h5.3v5.3h3.6V16H32v-3.5h-5.3z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-instagram" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path  d="M16.5 15c0-.3-.2-.5-.5-.5-1.5 0-2.7 1.1-2.7 2.5 0 .3.2.5.5.5s.5-.2.5-.5c0-.8.8-1.5 1.6-1.5.4 0 .6-.2.6-.5zm3.8 2c0 2.2-2 4-4.3 4s-4.3-1.8-4.3-4 1.9-4 4.3-4 4.3 1.9 4.3 4zM3 26.1h26V24H3v2.1zM22.5 17c0-3.4-2.9-6.1-6.6-6.1S9.4 13.6 9.4 17s2.9 6.1 6.6 6.1 6.5-2.8 6.5-6.1zM5.3 6.9h6.6V4.8H5.3v2.1zM3 9.9h26v-4H15L13.9 8H3v1.9zm28.2-4v20.3c0 1.1-1 2.1-2.2 2.1H3c-1.2 0-2.2-.9-2.2-2.1V5.9c0-1.1 1-2.1 2.2-2.1h26c1.2 0 2.2.9 2.2 2.1z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-twitter" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path  d="M30.8 5.2c-1.1.6-2.3.9-3.5 1.1 1.2-.8 2.3-2.4 2.6-4-1.2.8-2.4 1.4-3.9 1.8-1.1-1.4-2.6-2.4-4.4-2.4-3.3 0-6 3.2-6 7.2 0 .6.1 1 .2 1.6-5-.3-9.5-3.1-12.5-7.5-.6 1-.9 2.4-.9 3.6 0 2.5 1 4.7 2.6 6-.9 0-1.9-.4-2.7-.8v.1c0 3.5 2.1 6.4 4.9 7.1-.6.2-1 .3-1.6.3-.4 0-.8-.1-1.1-.1.8 2.8 3 4.9 5.7 5-2.1 2-4.7 3.1-7.5 3.1-.6 0-.9 0-1.5-.1 2.6 2.1 5.9 3.2 9.3 3.2 11.2 0 17.2-11 17.2-20.5v-.8c1.2-1.2 2.2-2.4 3.1-3.9z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="a-we-in-vcontacte" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32"  >
<path  d="M22.6 15.1c1.1-1.5 1.9-3.4 1.9-5.6 0-4.7-3.6-8.6-8-8.6h-10V31h12c4.4 0 8-3.9 8-8.6 0-3.1-1.5-5.8-3.9-7.3zM12.5 5.3h3.2c1.8 0 3.2 2 3.2 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.2 4.3h-3.2V5.3zm4.9 21.4h-5v-8.6h5c1.9 0 3.3 2 3.3 4.3s-1.4 4.3-3.3 4.3z"></path>
</symbol>

<a xlink:href="https://ru-ru.facebook.com/"> <use y="8" xlink:href="#a-we-in-facebook"></use> </a>
<a xlink:href="https://plus.google.com/" > <use y="8"  x="50" xlink:href="#a-we-in-google"></use></a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.instagram.com/" ><use y="8"  x="100" xlink:href="#a-we-in-instagram"></use></a>
<a xlink:href="https://twitter.com/" ><use y="8"  x="150" xlink:href="#a-we-in-twitter"></use></a>
<a xlink:href="https://vk.com/feed" ><use y="8"  x="200" xlink:href="#a-we-in-vcontacte"></use></a>
</svg>
```

Comment: 1-й вариант может застраховать от того, что не будут попадать части соседних изображений, но на экране все-таки будет обрезанное изображение...
если делать больше пустого места вокруг картинки, то нужное изображение будет показано полностью, но будут проблемы с вертикальным выравниванием в разных браузерах относительно остального текста.... 2-й вариант - это на крайний случай, потому что используется цмс и это потянет переработки многих шаблонов..., а также уже много работы сделано... проще использовать png-спрайт как по старинке,  но хочется использовать преимущества векторной графики...

Comment: @Alex так и используйте преимущества векторной графики. Я так ненавязчиво намекнул, что можно использовать мой вариант. Ведь это отдельный файл SVG, который можно вставить целиком, как блок в HTML и иконки будут выглядеть, как есть, их не надо дополнительно позиционировать, изображения не обрежутся и т.д  а ссылки на соц. сети можно вставить внутри этого блока SVG. Используйте этот файл, как готовый кирпичик в своем проекте

Comment: @Alex посмотрите ещё вариант - соц. иконки одним блоком

Comment: @Alex еще вариант с работающими ссылками на соцсети внутри SVG блока. Теперь он полностью автономный.

Answer (score 3):

#### Вариант 1: удаление у исходных файлов ViewBox

Используйте плагины gulp-imagemin и imagemin-svgo для удаление ViewBox:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    svg-sprites = require('gulp-svg-sprites'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

gulp.task('svg-sprites:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.theme.img_svg_src + '*.svg')
    .pipe(imagemin([
        imageminSvgo({
            plugins: [
                {removeViewBox: true}
            ]
        })
    ]))
    .pipe(svgSprite())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.img_src + 'dict'))
    .pipe(filter(options.theme.img_src + 'dict/svg/*.svg')) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.img_src + 'dict'));
});
```

#### Вариант 2: заменить SVG-спрайт на иконочный шрифт

Предпочтительней было бы использование иконичного шрифта вместо спрайтов. И у этого метода есть ряд преимуществ:

1. Более меньший вес шрифта, чем спрайта;
2. Гибкость стилизации через CSS;
3. Меньший вес CSS.

Для генерации иконочного шрифта я бы посоветовал такую комбинацию:

```
// Generate icon font
gulp.task('iconfont', function() {
    var
        fontName = 'icon-font',
        cssClass = 'i';
    // Исходные SVG-файлы
    gulp.src(['./fonts/icon-font/*.svg'])
        .pipe(iconfontCss({
            fontName: fontName,
            cssClass: cssClass,
            path: './styl/mixins/icon-font.styl',
            targetPath: '../../styl/components/font/icon-font.styl',
            fontPath: '../fonts/'
        }))
        .pipe(iconfont({
            fontName: fontName,
            prependUnicode: true,
            normalize: true,
            formats: ['svg','ttf','woff','woff2']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/fonts/'));
});
```

Миски для стилей, который берется из этой строки `path: './styl/mixins/icon-font.styl'` будет выглядеть так:

```
@font-face
    font-family "<%= fontName %>"
    src: url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff') format('woff'),
         url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.svg#<%= fontName %>') format('svg')

[class*="i-"]
    position relative
    display inline-block
    width 1em
    height 1em
    &:before
        font 14px '<%= fontName %>'
        font-size inherit
        text-rendering auto
        speak none
        font-variant normal
        text-transform none
        color inherit
        position absolute
        top 50%
        left 50%
        transform translate(-50%, -50%)

<% _.each(glyphs, function(glyph) { %>
.<%= cssClass %>-<%= glyph.fileName %>:before
  content "\<%= glyph.codePoint %>"
<% }); %>
```

После генерации шрифта все, что вам нужно будет сделать, это подключить сгенированный CSS к вашему сайту или инглудить его к главному CSS-файлу, а затем использовать таким образом:

```
<span class="i-<<имя исходного SVG-файла>>"></span>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T, не пойму, о чем вы.

Comment: @Alexandr_T у меня лично один голос остался и я его только что подарил вам. Ненужно обвинять меня в минусовании. Меня самого сегодня по всем вопросам кто-то массово минусовал.

Comment: Может потому, что я дал ответ позже?

Comment: @Alexandr_T и за что вы меня минусуете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54078/discussion-between-alexandr-t-and-vadizar).

Comment: какое преимущество использование плагинов gulp-imagemin и imagemin-svgo перед gulp-svgmin?

Comment: @Alex дело в том, что с помощью gulp-imagemin можно объединить и выполнить сжатие всей графики в одной задачи.