# Как поменять размер иконок в svg-спрайте?

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт

Использую на проекте *svg-спрайт*. Спрайт собирал с помощью *gulp* и плагинов (*gulp-svg-symbols, gulp-svgmin, gulp-cheerio*). Проблема в том, что при изменение размера иконки в *CSS*, она изменяется в непонятных мне пропорциях. Я задал иконке `width: 46px`, но она не увеличилась на `46px`. На скриншоте видно, как поле вокруг иконки стало размером `46px`, а сама иконка нет. Как правильно контролировать размер иконок в *svg-спрайте*?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*[Ссылка на картинку](http://joxi.ru/Y2LER1Os5PDvA6)*

**Пример кода, который я использую:**

```css
.nav__icon-check {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
  <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#4F4F4F" d="M21.848 4.098c.845.798.845 1.999 0 2.796L8.571 19.48l13.277 12.585c.845.803.845 2.001 0 2.8a2.12 2.12 0 0 1-2.952 0L4.149 20.878c-.847-.798-.847-1.996 0-2.794L18.896 4.098c.422-.4 1.059-.596 1.476-.596.42 0 1.057.196 1.476.596z"/> 
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="check" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.818 16.998h-.023a1.792 1.792 0 0 1-1.285-.557L.463 10.048A1.645 1.645 0 0 1 .584 7.65a1.818 1.818 0 0 1 2.495.116l4.765 5.037L19.942.548A1.82 1.82 0 0 1 22.44.482c.707.648.739 1.721.067 2.402L9.101 16.469a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.283.529"/> 
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="nav__icon-check">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#check"> </use>
</svg>
```

*[Пример на codepan.](http://codepen.io/Vavilkin/pen/VpaqGd)*

Comment: Покажите код, наугад проблему нельзя решить.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, добавил ссылку с примером на codepen

Comment: Эмм... у SVG надо менять размер, а не у блока родительского

Comment: Так я и обращаюсь к тегу svg по классу nav__icon-check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем-то, у вас при увеличении SVG-элемента иконка увеличивается, но она изначально не занимает всё полотно, потому это слабо заметно. Вам надо изменить значение `viewbox`-атрибута на, скажем `"0 0 25 25"`. А дальше увеличивайте/уменьшайте иконку сколько душе угодно.

```css
.nav__icon-check {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
  <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#4F4F4F" d="M21.848 4.098c.845.798.845 1.999 0 2.796L8.571 19.48l13.277 12.585c.845.803.845 2.001 0 2.8a2.12 2.12 0 0 1-2.952 0L4.149 20.878c-.847-.798-.847-1.996 0-2.794L18.896 4.098c.422-.4 1.059-.596 1.476-.596.42 0 1.057.196 1.476.596z"/> 
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="check" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.818 16.998h-.023a1.792 1.792 0 0 1-1.285-.557L.463 10.048A1.645 1.645 0 0 1 .584 7.65a1.818 1.818 0 0 1 2.495.116l4.765 5.037L19.942.548A1.82 1.82 0 0 1 22.44.482c.707.648.739 1.721.067 2.402L9.101 16.469a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.283.529"/> 
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="nav__icon-check">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#check"> </use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А можно ли как-то автоматизировать проставление viewbox при сборке спрайта? Ведь значение viewBox="0 0 100 100" добавилось автоматически при моей сборки.

Comment: посмотрите ответы здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629465/svg-sprite-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5