# Почему svg отображается в маленьком размере?

Tags: html, css, svg, img, background

Есть картинка в svg см. пример1
[image: пример1]

но в chrome и firefox отображается в очень маленьком размере см. пример2
[image: пример2]

Код, которым встраивал:

```css
.singl_in::after {
 content: '';
 width: 19px;
 height: 24px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: url('i/icon-svg/icon-singl-in.svg') no-repeat top left;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="singl_in">Singl in <img width="19" height="24" src="i/icon-svg/icon-singl-in.svg" alt=""></div>
```

как видно, я вставлял картинку через тег **img** и через свойство background.
Задавал размеры background-size: 19px 24px; не помогло.

Код самого изображения svg:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 252 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 252 144;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M139.8,82.3l-7.6-3.8c-0.7-0.4-1.2-1.1-1.2-1.9v-2.7c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.6-0.8c1-1.4,1.8-3,2.4-4.6c1.1-0.5,1.9-1.6,1.9-2.9
  v-3.2c0-0.8-0.3-1.5-0.8-2.1V56c0-0.4,0.2-3.1-1.7-5.2c-1.6-1.9-4.3-2.8-7.9-2.8c-3.6,0-6.3,0.9-7.9,2.8c-1.9,2.2-1.7,4.8-1.7,5.2
  v4.3c-0.5,0.6-0.8,1.3-0.8,2.1v3.2c0,1,0.4,1.9,1.2,2.5c0.7,2.9,2.3,5.1,2.8,5.8v2.6c0,0.8-0.4,1.5-1.1,1.9l-7.1,3.9
  c-2.3,1.3-3.8,3.7-3.8,6.3v2.6c0,3.8,12,4.8,18.4,4.8c6.4,0,18.4-1,18.4-4.8v-2.4C143.8,86,142.3,83.5,139.8,82.3L139.8,82.3z
   M139.8,82.3"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Может это изображение стоит как-то по другому конвертировать ? у меня исходников нет, прислали уже такое изображение.

Comment: а вам, какой фактически  размер  svg изображения нужен на странице 19х24 ? Напишите, исправлю файл svg и объясню почему так происходит в вашем случае.

Comment: смотрите, блок singl_in по размерам (19x24), но иконка в нем намного меньше, размеры блока видно по красной границе, изображение тоже хочу сделать 19x24, но по факту оно меньше почему-то, был бы очень вам признателен за помощь

Comment: css еще остальной покажите, кроме того, что есть у вас в вопросе, так как окружающие блоки тоже могут оказывать влияние на масштабирование иконки. Файл SVG уже в работе, на переделке И я так понимаю не обязательно добавлять svg как background Есть более лучшие способы,

Comment: хорошо, давайте увеличим размер пропорционально, чтобы наглядней видно было, сейчас скину код

Comment: `<div class="block"></div>
<img width="150" height="189" src="i/icon-svg/icon-singl-in.svg" alt="">`

Comment: `.block {
 width: 150px;
 height: 189px;
 background: url('i/icon-svg/icon-singl-in.svg') no-repeat top left;
 background-size: contain;
}`

Comment: она все равно, меньше чем нужно http://prntscr.com/evzepp

Comment: то есть по факту, ее размер сейчас 22px на 30px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="19" height="24" viewBox="192 85 76 96" style="border:1px solid red">
<g transform="scale(1.85)">
 <path d="M139.8,82.3l-7.6-3.8c-0.7-0.4-1.2-1.1-1.2-1.9v-2.7c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.6-0.8c1-1.4,1.8-3,2.4-4.6c1.1-0.5,1.9-1.6,1.9-2.9
  v-3.2c0-0.8-0.3-1.5-0.8-2.1V56c0-0.4,0.2-3.1-1.7-5.2c-1.6-1.9-4.3-2.8-7.9-2.8c-3.6,0-6.3,0.9-7.9,2.8c-1.9,2.2-1.7,4.8-1.7,5.2
  v4.3c-0.5,0.6-0.8,1.3-0.8,2.1v3.2c0,1,0.4,1.9,1.2,2.5c0.7,2.9,2.3,5.1,2.8,5.8v2.6c0,0.8-0.4,1.5-1.1,1.9l-7.1,3.9
  c-2.3,1.3-3.8,3.7-3.8,6.3v2.6c0,3.8,12,4.8,18.4,4.8c6.4,0,18.4-1,18.4-4.8v-2.4C143.8,86,142.3,83.5,139.8,82.3L139.8,82.3z
   M139.8,82.3"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Переделал SVG файл

Иконка SVG сейчас размером 19х24px
Для этого добавил `viewPort width="19"` `height="24"`
 Далее с помощью `viewBox="192 85 76 96"` заставил иконку уменьшиться в размерах, отцентрировал относительно `viewport` - это красный прямоугольник, который нужен  был для настройки SVG изображения.
При добавлении в HTML уберите строчку из шапки SVG файла - `style="border:1px solid red"`

Можете добавлять код svg инлайновым способом, то есть оберните svg в див контейнер и копируйте код в HTML

**Дополнительного масштабирование не требуется, иконка переработана под ваши размеры.**
Если вас не устраивает инлайновый способ добавления svg, используйте тег `object`

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="icon-singl-in.svg" width="19" height="24" >
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

[Другие способы](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047) добавления SVG в HTML страницу

Comment: @Teem Посмотрите результат и если вас, устраивает решение отметьте его галочкой

Comment: Вы подстроили иконку, это здорово, но у меня еще таких много, мне бы хотелось понять принцип, как вы это сделали? неужели в ручную в атрибуте viewBox каждое значение подгоняли ?

Comment: @Teem так я вроде всё объяснил в комментариях к своему ответу. Других путей нет, если иконка, была так изначально нарисована. Если хотите подробно разобраться, как масштабируются иконки, центрируются почитайте вот эту статью на нашем сайте  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748 и ещё неужели мой труд ничего не стоит?

Comment: извините меня за дотошность, но я лишь уточню:  Прописываем в svg  необходимые значения viewPort width="19" height="24" и дальше изменяем значения атрибута viewBox="192 85 76 96" на глаз вручную, пока не получим желаемый результат, все верно ?

Comment: @верно , но вручную,  методом тыка, не понимая принципа взаимодействия viewport и viewBox в некоторых случаях вряд ли получится- читайте статью, которую дал. Это ведь интересно - разобраться один раз и потом действовать быстро и уверенно

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо вам за уделенное время моей проблеме, для меня это было важно. Я ознакомился со статьей, мне кажется есть какой-нибудь способ конвертировать это изображение, я еще поищу

Comment: отметить не могу, моя репутация не позволяет

Comment: А сейчас, можете отметить?.  Поверьте моему опыту - нет других способов. Иконки рисуются вручную, порой дизайнер, который рисует, даже не догадывается о всех проблемах, которые могут возникнуть.