# Тултип внутри файла SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

В топике [Tooltip с вырезами у стрелки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/665642/28748)  рассматривались варианты оформления тултипа нарисованными средствами css или svg применительно к блокам Html.
Но в самом svg есть  свой тултип, со стандартной формой отображения и текстом, который берется из тегов `<title> любой текст </title>`
 Обязательным условием для появления текста тултипа является нахождение тегов `<title>` внутри тегов группы `<g>` или внутри вложенного `<svg> <title> </title></svg>`

Текст появляется при наведении и удержании курсора на блоке.

См. пример ниже:

```html
 <svg width="300" height="120" viewBox="0 0 300 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
  
<g>
 <title> Синий прямоугольник</title>
 <rect  x="10" y="40" width="100" height="40" fill="dodgerblue" />
</g> 
   <g> 
   <title> Зеленый круг</title>
   <circle cx="150" cy="60" r="20" fill="yellowgreen" />
   </g> 
   
   <g> 
   <title> Оранжевый квадрат </title>
   <rect  x="190" y="40" width="40" height="40" fill="orange" />
   </g>
 
 </svg>
```

**Вопрос**

Возможно изменение формы, цвета тултипа  svg?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, зависит только от браузера, так же как и с alert() в js.