# Как растянуть текст svg по всей ширине контейнера?

Tags: html, css, svg

Растягивание самого SVG-элемента никак не помогает. Также пробовал добавить `viewBox='50% 50% 100% 100%'` и это не привело ни к каким результатам.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

tspan {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text>
      <tspan x="0" y="0">The</tspan>
      <tspan x="51.694" y="0"letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="58.408" y="0">chair</tspan>
      <tspan x="123.432" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="130.146" y="0">has</tspan>
      <tspan x="178.515" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="185.229" y="0">been</tspan>
      <tspan x="251.967" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="258.68" y="0">used</tspan>
      <tspan x="323.734" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="330.448" y="0">since </tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="13">antiquity,</tspan>
      <tspan x="120.073" y="13" letter-spacing="10"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="139.05" y="13">although</tspan>
      <tspan x="254.158" y="13" letter-spacing="10"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="273.135" y="13">for</tspan>
      <tspan x="308.145" y="13" letter-spacing="10"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="327.122" y="13">many </tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="26">centuries</tspan>
      <tspan x="121.729" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="129.801" y="26">it</tspan>
      <tspan x="144.801" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="152.874" y="26">was</tspan>
      <tspan x="206.224" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="214.297" y="26">a</tspan>
      <tspan x="230.981" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="239.054" y="26">symbolic</tspan>
      <tspan x="355.744" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="363.817" y="26">ar</tspan>
      <tspan x="390.491" y="26">-</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="39">ticle</tspan>
      <tspan x="53.35" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="61.736" y="39">of</tspan>
      <tspan x="86.755" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="95.142" y="39">state</tspan>
      <tspan x="160.181" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="168.567" y="39">and</tspan>
      <tspan x="218.621" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="227.007" y="39">dignity</tspan>
      <tspan x="313.726" y="39"></tspan>
      <tspan x="322.112" y="39">rather</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="52">than</tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: [Canvas](http://w3pro.ru/article/svg-ili-canvas-slozhnosti-vybora) ? (JavaScript)  выводить с его пощью отображение svg в броузере.

Comment: Подробнее про Canvas [тут](https://webformyself.com/canvas-ili-svg-kak-vybrat-pravilnyj-instrument-dlya-raboty/) и [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Растягивание текста делается с помощью атрибутов [textLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength) и [lengthAdjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/lengthAdjust).

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 180px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text x="10" y="50" textLength="580" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">antiquity, although for</text>
    <text x="10" y="80" textLength="580" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">many centuries it was a</text>
    <text x="10" y="110" textLength="580" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">symbolic article of state</text>
    <text x="10" y="140" textLength="580" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">and dignity rather than</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Смотрите также:** [Как растянуть текст по ширине блока div](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836558/), где присутствует решение через JS/JQ.

Comment: Поправил снова отступы, если вы не против

Comment: @Arthur, как вы узнаёте о новых ответах?

Comment: " It's magic=) ". Сидел и рассматривал данный вопрос, затем заметил повторное обновление вашего ответа, вскоре снова исправил отступы. Увы `SVG` не приводится в порядок, может быть это исправят, частенько приходится править.

Comment: @Arthur, решил заодно и подобный вопрос: [Как растянуть текст по ширине блока div](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836558/), где присутствует решение через JS/JQ.

Comment: Уже бегу править:D

Answer (score 2):

Не вполне уверен, что понял вопрос. Такого решения будет достаточно?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('svg').each(function() {
    var svg = $(this);
    var text = svg.find('text');
    var bbox = text.get(0).getBBox(); 

    svg.get(0).setAttribute('viewBox', 
                            [bbox.x,
                             bbox.y,
                             bbox.width,
                             bbox.height].join(' '));
  });
}, 100);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

tspan {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text>
      <tspan x="0" y="0">The</tspan>
      <tspan x="51.694" y="0"letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="58.408" y="0">chair</tspan>
      <tspan x="123.432" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="130.146" y="0">has</tspan>
      <tspan x="178.515" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="185.229" y="0">been</tspan>
      <tspan x="251.967" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="258.68" y="0">used</tspan>
      <tspan x="323.734" y="0" letter-spacing="-1"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="330.448" y="0">since </tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="13">antiquity,</tspan>
      <tspan x="120.073" y="13" letter-spacing="10"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="139.05" y="13">although</tspan>
      <tspan x="254.158" y="13" letter-spacing="10"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="273.135" y="13">for</tspan>
      <tspan x="308.145" y="13" letter-spacing="10"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="327.122" y="13">many </tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="26">centuries</tspan>
      <tspan x="121.729" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="129.801" y="26">it</tspan>
      <tspan x="144.801" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="152.874" y="26">was</tspan>
      <tspan x="206.224" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="214.297" y="26">a</tspan>
      <tspan x="230.981" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="239.054" y="26">symbolic</tspan>
      <tspan x="355.744" y="26"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="363.817" y="26">ar</tspan>
      <tspan x="390.491" y="26">-</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="39">ticle</tspan>
      <tspan x="53.35" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="61.736" y="39">of</tspan>
      <tspan x="86.755" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="95.142" y="39">state</tspan>
      <tspan x="160.181" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="168.567" y="39">and</tspan>
      <tspan x="218.621" y="39"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="227.007" y="39">dignity</tspan>
      <tspan x="313.726" y="39"></tspan>
      <tspan x="322.112" y="39">rather</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="52">than</tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это решение, но есть ли возможность решить без JavaScript?

Comment: Возможность есть, уберите скрипт и добавьте в svg атрибут viewbox="0 -27 408 85". Но есть один нюанс, чтобы быстро узнать параметры для `viewbox`, я получаю `boundingbox` элемента с помощью jQ. Другого способа, к сожалению, не знаю.