# Как растянуть текст по ширине блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Каким образом можно решить такую задачу?

Есть несколько div в которых лежат 2 текстовые строки "p". Текст в эти строки подставляется динамически пользователем при вводе в input. Шрифт у текста в каждом блоке разный. Размер шрифта в первой строке 25px, в нижней 20.

Как сделать так, чтобы ширина текста была одинаковой, но при этом font-size  второй строки был всегда меньше размера первой?

https://gyazo.com/585a1b62e7338b2f8464c989c18661c2

[image]

Comment: А что вы понимаете под шириной текста? За счет чего текст должен становится шире?

Comment: под шириной понимаю то сколько пикселей занимает в ширину строка, думаю за счет размера текста как то это регулировать, но мне не нравится этот вариант.

Comment: Никак. Я в первой напишу "ШШШШШШШШШШШШШШШШШ", а во второй "i" - и что ты с этим сделаешь?

Comment: Используй transform - так проще должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 разных способа решения вашей задачи: через SVG и JavaScript.

**Через SVG (решение #1):**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 125px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica
}

.name {
  font-size: 25px
}

.desc {
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text class="name" x="10" y="50" textLength="480" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Есть несколько div</text>
    <text class="desc" x="10" y="80" textLength="480" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">текст в эти строки подставляется</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Через SVG (решение #2):**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 125px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica
}

.name {
  font-size: 25px
}

.desc {
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text class="name" x="10" y="50" textLength="480" lengthAdjust="spacing">Есть несколько div</text>
    <text class="desc" x="10" y="80" textLength="480" lengthAdjust="spacing">текст в эти строки подставляется</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Через JavaScript:**

```js
$.fn.strech_text = function() {
  var elmt = $(this),
    cont_width = elmt.width(),
    txt = elmt.html(),
    one_line = $('<span class="stretch_it">' + txt + '</span>'),
    nb_char = elmt.text().length,
    spacing = cont_width / nb_char,
    txt_width;

  elmt.html(one_line);
  txt_width = one_line.width();

  if (txt_width < cont_width) {
    var char_width = txt_width / nb_char,
      ltr_spacing = spacing - char_width + (spacing - char_width) / nb_char;

    one_line.css({
      'letter-spacing': ltr_spacing
    });
  } else {
    one_line.contents().unwrap();
    elmt.addClass('justify');
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stretch').each(function() {
    $(this).strech_text();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 125px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  background-color: blue
}

.stretch_it {
  white-space: nowrap
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify
}

p {
  margin: 7px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica
}

.name {
  font-size: 25px
}

.desc {
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="stretch name">Есть несколько div</p>
  <p class="stretch desc">текст в эти строки подставляется</p>
</div>
```

Comment: У вопроса нет метки [tag:jquery], это предполагает ответы на чистом JavaScript'е.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function setSpText(e) {
  const el = (e instanceof Event) ? e.target : e; 
  let value = el.value, 
      outP  = document.querySelector(el.dataset.output || '');
  if (outP)
    value = (value.split('')).map(chr => `<span>${chr}</span>`).join(''); 
  outP.innerHTML = value; 
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for (let inp of document.querySelectorAll('.usertext')) {
    inp.addEventListener('input', setSpText); 
    setSpText(inp); 
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 400px; margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc; 
}

.line {
  display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
  margin: 0; 
}
.line.first  { font: 25px monospace; }
.line.second { font: 20px sans-serif; }

.line > span { flex: 0 0 auto; }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p class="line first"></p>
  <p class="line second"></p>
</div>

<input id="inp-first" class="usertext" data-output=".first" maxlength="20" value="Текст первой строки"><br>
<input id="inp-second" class="usertext" data-output=".second" maxlength="30" value="Мелкий текст второй строки">
```