# Трансформация фигуры - одной стороны

Tags: html, css

[image: Прямоугольник]

Как сделать такую фигуру. По сути, это просто прямоугольник, с не много трансформированной стороной + скругления

Comment: А может не мудрить и сделать svg?

Comment: Да так пока что и сделал. Кинул фоном СВГ. Но это не самый лучший вариант для адаптации. Как по мне...

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть а какой вариант Вас устроил бы, чистый CSS ?

Comment: да любой. Что бы не было проблем с адаптацией и наполнение разного текста. Я с такой фигурой первый раз столкнулся и понял, что не могу придумать как сделать её универсальной (растяжение по высоте и ширине без пропорций)

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть, а если border-image?

Comment: Всё равно же вопрос адаптации стоит.... 
Решил сделать svg на фон.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) .9em, rgba(0, 0, 250, .15) 1em) 0 0, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) .9em, rgba(0, 0, 250, .15) 1em) 0 0;
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.tip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 115px;
  margin: 37px 0;
  padding: 0px 7px 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
  border: 3px solid #090;
  border-top: none;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.tip:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #090;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skewY(-2.4deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-177.6deg, #fff 55%, transparent 55%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -19px;
  left: 27px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #090;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skewY(-31.4deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(31.4deg, #fff 51%, transparent 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="tip" contenteditable>Здесь можно редактировать текст, для проверки адаптивности. Все пропорции оригинала учтены. Проблема одна - нельзя сделать фон прозрачным.</div>
```

### Update

Связанный пример: [адаптивные тултипы с прозрачным фоном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/667483/28748)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYRvzQ - чуток подправил

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо. Покажите, где я промахнулся? Может от браузера зависит (тестировал на Win7+Chrome70)?

Comment: @UModeL ваш ответ лучший. Адаптивен при добавлении текста и изменении размера окна браузера!

Answer (score 4):

Основу для такой фигуры без трансформации можно сделать [тут](https://leaverou.github.io/bubbly/). После поправить немного стили для позиционирования треугольника внизу, отступов внутри фигуры и добавить css трансформацию `transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(-45deg);`.

```css
body {
    background: #00aabb;
}

.speech-bubble {
    margin: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(-45deg);
}

.speech-bubble::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 39px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    margin-left: -19.5px;
    margin-bottom: -39px;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble"></div>
```

[Сodepen](https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/EONpOB)

Comment: не совсем то что нужно. Тут идут на скос две стороны. А нужно, только верхняя

Comment: По картинке не совсем было видно, а скругление обязательно?

Comment: ага.. Там под дизайн нужно

Comment: Готово, если нужен будет текст внутри, то его без проблем можно повернуть обратной трансформацией

Comment: ну не совсем. попробуйте поиграться с размерами (адаптация)