# Как сверстать блок с контентом с "кривой" формой?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, svg

Есть такой блок с контентом, он может немного сжиматься в ширину (пикселей на 200) и резиновый в высоту

Можно ли как-то сверстать его не прибегая к костылям с картинками? В CSS3 полигоны вроде мало где работают ещё

[image]

Comment: А если его на border-image порезать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте фон svg, например, так:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 610 380" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#121c37;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#18283d;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0,380) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="url(#gradient1)">
    <path d="M80 2087 l0 -1652 153 -153 152 -152 2595 0 2595 0 153 153 152 152
0 1653 0 1652 -424 0 -424 0 -32 -50 -32 -50 -488 0 -489 0 -28 50 -28 50
-955 0 -956 0 -29 -50 -29 -50 -491 0 -490 0 -28 50 -28 50 -425 0 -424 0 0
-1653z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Для того, чтобы SVG был резиновым, обратите внимание на код `width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

SVG лучше делать отдельным файлом (предпочтительный способ), но также можно делать как часть значения `background` (**Внимание, представленный ниже код будет работать только в webkit-браузерах!**):

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 610 380" preserveAspectRatio="none"><defs><linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#121c37;" /><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#18283d;" /></linearGradient></defs><g transform="translate(0,380) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="url(#gradient1)"><path d="M80 2087 l0 -1652 153 -153 152 -152 2595 0 2595 0 153 153 152 152 0 1653 0 1652 -424 0 -424 0 -32 -50 -32 -50 -488 0 -489 0 -28 50 -28 50 -955 0 -956 0 -29 -50 -29 -50 -491 0 -490 0 -28 50 -28 50 -425 0 -424 0 0 -1653z" /></g></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Для того, чтобы код работал в MS Edge и Firefox символы внутри url должны быть escaped после кодировки utf8, поэтому заменим двойные кавычки на одинарные, `#` на `%23` и `%` на `%25`:

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 610 380' preserveAspectRatio='none'><defs><linearGradient id='gradient1' x1='0%25' y1='0%25' x2='0%25' y2='100%25'><stop offset='0%25' style='stop-color:%23121c37;' /><stop offset='100%25' style='stop-color:%2318283d;' /></linearGradient></defs><g transform='translate(0,380) scale(0.1,-0.1)' fill='url(%23gradient1)'><path d='M80 2087 l0 -1652 153 -153 152 -152 2595 0 2595 0 153 153 152 152 0 1653 0 1652 -424 0 -424 0 -32 -50 -32 -50 -488 0 -489 0 -28 50 -28 50 -955 0 -956 0 -29 -50 -29 -50 -491 0 -490 0 -28 50 -28 50 -425 0 -424 0 0 -1653z' /></g></svg>");
  background-size: 100% 100%;  /* Фикс для Firefox, чтобы изображение корректно растягивалось */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Также для корректного масштабирования в Fifefox добавляем `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

Comment: А как заставить его тянуться по высоте в зависимости от контента?

Comment: Нуу, что-то не работает http://savepic.ru/14598051.png

Comment: Спасибо! Ещё вопрос, что вы сделали в svg чтоб он стал резиновым? Мне дизайнер скинул версию с более правильным градиентом, https://hastebin.com/uhujufuyey.xml как его научится резинить?

Comment: @Fangog обратите внимание на шапку svg `width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"`. Также  пусть svg будет отдельным файлом всё-таки (так лучше для его сопровождаемости и поддержки браузерами).

Comment: Ещё при сильном вытягивании происходит вот что, исправляется ли это как-то? http://savepic.ru/14557137.png

Comment: @Fangog Ну зависит от задачи. Если у вас это одна-единственная картинка, которая не должна меняться, то решается просто правкой svg. Если подобных картинок много (то есть задача переиспользования стилей), или надо гибкий контейнер, или нужна анимация svg, то это уже совсем другая история и вполне тянет на отдельный конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

> Мне дизайнер скинул версию с более правильным градиентом,
>   hastebin.com/uhujufuyey.xml как его научится резинить?

Чтобы svg был адаптивным необходимо убрать из шапки svg файла атрибуты `viewport`, то есть в вашем примере от дизайнера необходимо удалить `width="1380px" height="865px"`.
Оставить только viewBox – `viewBox="0 0 2760 1730"`.
Как влияют **`viewport`** и **`viewBox`** на масштабирование и адаптивность svg можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

**Когда не указан `viewport (width, height)` они по умолчанию равны  `width="100%" height="100%"`**

В примере ниже svg изображение добавлено непосредственно (инлайн) в HTML страничку.

Проверена адаптивность фигуры в Chrome, Firefox, Opera. В IE11 фигура не адаптивна.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2760 1730" version="1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="#102036" stop-opacity="1" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="#0C1830" offset="50" />
      <stop stop-color="#1A2042" stop-opacity="1" offset="100" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path d="M0 784L0 0 1370 0 1370 784 1370 784 1299 855 1299 855 70 855 70 855 0 784ZM200 0L214 25 445 25 460 0 200 0ZM910 0L924 25 1155 25 1170 0 910 0Z" id="path-2" />
    <filter x="-4" y="-1" width="108" height="107" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-3">
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
      <feComposite in="shadowBlurOuter1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
      <feColorMatrix values="0" type="matrix" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="WEB" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="MAIN" transform="translate(-270.000000, -747.000000)">
      <g id="BLOCK" transform="translate(275.000000, 750.000000)">
        <g id="BG">
          <use fill="black" fill-opacity="1" filter="url(#filter-3)" xlink:href="#path-2" />
          <use fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-2" />
          <path stroke-opacity="0" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" d="M1 1L1 0 0 1 1 1ZM1370 1L1370 1 1370 0 1370 1ZM1370 784L1370 784 1370 784 1370 784 1370 783 1370 784ZM1299 855L1298 855 1299 855 1299 855 1299 855 1299 855ZM71 855L70 855 70 855 70 855 71 855 71 855ZM1 784L0 784 1 784 1 784ZM1 784L1 1 1370 1 1370 784 1299 855 71 855 1 784ZM214 26L199 0 461 0 445 26 214 26ZM909 0L1171 0 1155 26 924 26 909 0Z" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: И в вашем примере тоже не адаптивна , не тянется и даже по центру не находится , ответ ниже более правильный

Comment: @Максим Ленский расположение по центру не является признаком адаптивности. Если вы открываете сниппет "На всю страницу" изображение увеличивается? Если меняете величину окна браузера одновременно по горизонтали и вертикали, то изображение меняет свои размеры? Если так, то изображение адаптивно.   Сомнения у вас возникли вероятно, потому что иконка имеет огромные размеры, так бывает, когда рисуют в кореле. Посмотрите на код иконки она, если ничего не менять занимает почти весь экран. Чтобы она имела меньшие размеры я увеличил `viewBox="0 0 2760 1730"` уменьшив, тем самым её размеры вдвое.

Comment: Александр я не в коем случае не спорю но ваш пример выглядит не айс , но по вашему сайту я учился svg и моё мнение относительно этого примера не скажется на том как я отношусь именно к вам как к админу svg-art

Comment: @МаксимЛенский добавил в шапку файла svg  красную рамку, Которая показывает область действия svg. Сейчас более наглядно, почему так происходит.

Comment: Александр я же говорю я не спорю , с уважение Ленский

Comment: @Alexandr_T Просто если сделать пример с `viewBox="0 0 1380 865"` будет в разы наглядней. И можно тогда без этой красной рамки обойтись.