# Позиционирование SVG и вертикальное выравнивание <text>

Tags: css, svg

Есть SVG-файл:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" width="2cm" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<style>
  rect {
    fill:#AA0000;
  }
  circle {
    fill:#FFFFFF;
  }
  text {
    fill:#AA0000;
    font-family:PTSerif;
    font-size:1cm;
    text-anchor:middle;
  }
</style>

<rect width="2cm" height="100%" class="background"/>
<circle r="0.5cm" cx="50%" cy="50%" class="circle"/>
<text x="50%" y="50%">!</text>

</svg>
```

Отображается так:

[image: Изображение]

Как выровнять `text` строго по середине по вертикали? И  какие ещё существуют способы позиционирования объектов в SVG файле?

Comment: @Qwertiy Немного изменил твою правку, частично вернул назад, так как там был авторский вопрос про общие способы позиционирования в SVG на который я ответил.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, спасибо! Похоже, что-то при вставке сниппета пошло не так, потому что я совершенно не собирался это удалять и не трогал текст.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для вертикального выравнивания используйте [dominant-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) (поддерживается в Chrome, Opera, Firefox):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" width="2cm" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>
rect {
fill:#AA0000;
}
circle {
fill:#FFFFFF;
}
text {
fill:#AA0000;
font-family:PTSerif;
font-size:1cm;
text-anchor:middle;
}
</style>
<rect width="2cm" height="100%" class="background"/>
<circle r="0.5cm" cx="50%" cy="50%" class="circle"/>
<text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="central ">!</text>
</svg>
```

Также можно выравниваться `text` атрибутом [dy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy) (поддерживается в Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE, Edge):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" width="2cm" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>
rect {
  fill:#AA0000;
}
circle {
  fill:#FFFFFF;
}
text {
  fill:#AA0000;
  font-family:PTSerif;
  font-size:1cm;
  text-anchor:middle;
}
</style>
<rect width="2cm" height="100%" class="background"/>
<circle r="0.5cm" cx="50%" cy="50%" class="circle"/>
<text x="50%" y="50%" dy="0.3em">!</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 15):

> какие существуют способы позиционирования объектов в SVG файле?

Способов позиционирования объектов svg внутри файла *.svg достаточно много.

В данном посте не рассматривается позиционирование с помощью правил CSS, только SVG

### #1 Позиционирование с помощью `<use>`

Создав в секции `<defs>` любой объект svg, например круг, можно его в дальнейшем многократно использовать с помощью команды `<use>`, позиционируя клоны фигур координатами  `x` и `y`.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid grey;">

<defs>
 <circle id="crc1" r="25" />
</defs>
 
 <use x="26" y="26" fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 <use x="200" y="26" fill="mediumpurple"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 <use x="374" y="26" fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 
 <use x="26" y="200" fill="mediumpurple"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 <use x="200" y="200" fill="dodgerblue"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 <use x="374" y="200" fill="mediumpurple"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 
<use x="26" y="374" fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 <use x="200" y="374" fill="mediumpurple"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 <use x="374" y="374" fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use> 
 
 </svg>
```

### #2 Позиционирование  `preserveAspectRatio`

**Горизонтальное позиционирование**

Структура файла построена на вложении в родительский SVG дочерних svg со своими значениями `viewBox` и `preserveAspectRatio`

```
<svg  width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" pserveAspectRatio="none" >

<!-- Позиционируется в левый верхний угол -->
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" > ...  </svg>


 <!-- Позиционируется в середине -->
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" > ...  </svg>

  <!-- Позиционируется в правый верхний угол -->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" > ...  </svg>
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" >

<defs>
 <circle id="crc1"   r="25" transform="translate(26 26)"/>
</defs>

 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
 <use  fill="dodgerblue"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
 <use  fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" >
 <use  fill="teal"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 </svg>
```

**Вертикальное позиционирование**

Структура та же, что и для горизонтального позиционирования, отличие в значениях во вложенных `viewBox`

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" >

<defs>
 <circle id="crc1"  x="126" r="25" transform="translate(26 26)"/>
</defs>

 <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
 <use  fill="dodgerblue"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
 <use  fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
 <use  fill="teal"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 </svg>
```

### #3 Позиционирование  viewBox

**Горизонтальное позиционирование**

Первые два параметра x-min, y-min `viewBox="0 0 300 300` отвечают за расположение начала пользовательской системы координат относительно `viewport` 
Изменяя их значения можно сдвигать svg изображение по горизонтали и вертикали. Подробнее [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748) и [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%20viewport%20%D0%B8%20viewBox)

Структура файла svg точно такая же, как и для способа позиционирования  с `preserveAspectRatio` Только надо иметь ввиду, что изменяя у viewBox координаты влево мы сдвигаем изображение вправо, а для вертикальной координаты отрицательные значения сдвигают изображение вверх.
 *Другими словами - отрицательные координаты  viewBox двигают изображение в положительном направлении.*

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid grey" >

<defs>
 <circle id="crc1"  r="25" transform="translate(26 26)"/>
</defs>

 <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300"  >
 <use  fill="dodgerblue"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 <svg viewBox="-125 0 300 300" >
 <use  fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
  <svg viewBox="-249 0 300 300">
 <use  fill="teal"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 </svg>
```

### Позиционирование viewBox

**Вертикальное позиционирование**

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid grey" >

<defs>
 <circle id="crc1"  r="25" transform="translate(26 26)"/>
</defs>

 <svg viewBox="-125 0 300 300"  >
 <use  fill="dodgerblue"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 <svg viewBox="-125 -125 300 300" >
 <use  fill="violet"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
  <svg viewBox="-125 -249 300 300">
 <use  fill="teal"  xlink:href="#crc1"> </use>  
 </svg>
 
 </svg>
```

### #4 Позиционирование с использованием `translate`

*Универсальный и самый простой для освоения способ позиционирования svg изображений.*

В основе позиционирования команда - `transform="translate(100 100)"`, атрибуты которой сдвигают целиком изображение или его фрагменты по координатным осям.
Положительные значения атрибутов сдвигают изображение вправо и вниз.
 Отрицательные значения - влево и вверх.

Структура файла:

```
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid grey;" >


         <!-- Иконка по центру -->
 <svg id="swithCamera" width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 48 48" transform="translate(110 100)"  >
  код svg иконки ...  
</svg>

 <!-- Иконка в Левом верхнем углу -->
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(1 1)">
  код  svg иконки ...
</svg>

<!-- Иконка в вверху по центру -->
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(130 1)">
   код  svg иконки ...
 </svg>

 <!-- Иконка в правом верхнем углу -->
<svg   width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(250 1)" >
   код  svg иконки ... 
</svg>
 <!-- Закрывающий тег корневого svg -->
 </svg>
```

В корневой тег `<svg> ... /svg>`вложены дочерние изображения svg, к каждому из них применяется команда `transform="translate(x y)"` для позиционирования.

**Пример кода ниже:**

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<body>
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid grey;" >


         <!-- Иконка по центру -->
 <svg id="swithCamera" width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 48 48" transform="translate(110 100)"  >
 
 <g >
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M33.9,12.1H14.2L17.6,7c0.4-0.6,1-0.9,1.7-0.9h9.6c0.7,0,1.3,0.3,1.7,0.9L33.9,12.1z"/>
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M14,11H8V9.2C8,8.5,8.5,8,9.2,8h3.6C13.5,8,14,8.5,14,9.2V11z"/>
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M40,42H8c-2.2,0-4-1.8-4-4V14c0-2.2,1.8-4,4-4h32c2.2,0,4,1.8,4,4v24C44,40.2,42.2,42,40,42z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#E8EAF6" d="M34,25c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10c-2.4,0-4.6,0.8-6.3,2.2l1.2,1.6c1.4-1.1,3.1-1.8,5.1-1.8c4.4,0,8,3.6,8,8h-3.5    l4.5,5.6l4.5-5.6H34z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#E8EAF6" d="M29.1,31.2C27.7,32.3,25.9,33,24,33c-4.4,0-8-3.6-8-8h3.5L15,19.4L10.5,25H14c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10    c2.4,0,4.6-0.8,6.3-2.2L29.1,31.2z"/>
 </g>
</g> 
</svg>

 <!-- Иконка в Левом верхнем углу -->
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(1 1)">

    <path  fill="#5E35B1" d="M 3 5 L 3 27 L 14 27 L 14 25 L 5 25 L 5 7 L 27 7 L 27 15 L 29 16 L 29 5 L 3 5 z M 7 9 L 7 23 L 14 23 L 14.40625 21 L 9 21 L 9 11 L 23 11 L 23 14 L 25 14.3125 L 25 9 L 7 9 z M 24 16 C 19.593567 16 16 19.593567 16 24 C 16 28.406433 19.593567 32 24 32 C 28.406433 32 32 28.406433 32 24 C 32 19.593567 28.406433 16 24 16 z M 24 18 C 27.325553 18 30 20.674447 30 24 C 30 27.325553 27.325553 30 24 30 C 20.674447 30 18 27.325553 18 24 C 18 20.674447 20.674447 18 24 18 z M 23 20 L 23 23 L 20 23 L 20 25 L 23 25 L 23 28 L 25 28 L 25 25 L 28 25 L 28 23 L 25 23 L 25 20 L 23 20 z"/>
 
</svg>

<!-- Иконка в вверху по центру -->
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(130 1)">
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M 0 8 L 0 9 L 0 23 L 0 24 L 1 24 L 2 24 L 2 25 L 6 25 L 6 24 L 26 24 L 26 25 L 30 25 L 30 24 L 31 24 L 32 24 L 32 23 L 32 9 L 32 8 L 31 8 L 1 8 L 0 8 z M 2 10 L 30 10 L 30 22 L 2 22 L 2 10 z M 23 11 C 20.250421 11 18 13.250421 18 16 C 18 18.749579 20.250421 21 23 21 C 25.749579 21 28 18.749579 28 16 C 28 13.250421 25.749579 11 23 11 z M 4 13 L 4 15 L 6 15 L 6 13 L 4 13 z M 8 13 L 8 15 L 10 15 L 10 13 L 8 13 z M 12 13 L 12 15 L 14 15 L 14 13 L 12 13 z M 23 13 C 24.668699 13 26 14.331301 26 16 C 26 17.668699 24.668699 19 23 19 C 21.331301 19 20 17.668699 20 16 C 20 14.331301 21.331301 13 23 13 z M 4 17 L 4 19 L 6 19 L 6 17 L 4 17 z M 8 17 L 8 19 L 10 19 L 10 17 L 8 17 z M 12 17 L 12 19 L 14 19 L 14 17 L 12 17 z"/> 
 </svg>
 
 
 <!-- Иконка в правом верхнем углу -->
<svg   width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(250 1)" >
    <path fill="crimson" d="M 3 5 L 3 27 L 14 27 L 14 25 L 5 25 L 5 7 L 27 7 L 27 15 L 29 16 L 29 5 L 3 5 z M 7 9 L 7 23 L 14 23 L 14.40625 21 L 9 21 L 9 11 L 23 11 L 23 14 L 25 14.3125 L 25 9 L 7 9 z M 24 16 C 19.593567 16 16 19.593567 16 24 C 16 28.406433 19.593567 32 24 32 C 28.406433 32 32 28.406433 32 24 C 32 19.593567 28.406433 16 24 16 z M 24 18 C 27.325553 18 30 20.674447 30 24 C 30 27.325553 27.325553 30 24 30 C 20.674447 30 18 27.325553 18 24 C 18 20.674447 20.674447 18 24 18 z M 21.71875 20.28125 L 20.28125 21.71875 L 22.5625 24 L 20.28125 26.28125 L 21.71875 27.71875 L 24 25.4375 L 26.28125 27.71875 L 27.71875 26.28125 L 25.4375 24 L 27.71875 21.71875 L 26.28125 20.28125 L 24 22.5625 L 21.71875 20.28125 z"/>
</svg>

<!-- Иконка в правом нижнем углу -->
<svg   width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(250 250)" >

 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M 3 6 L 3 7 L 3 25 L 3 26 L 4 26 L 28 26 L 29 26 L 29 25 L 29 7 L 29 6 L 28 6 L 4 6 L 3 6 z M 5 8 L 8.25 8 L 9.59375 10 L 8.25 12 L 5 12 L 5 8 z M 10.65625 8 L 13.0625 8 L 14.40625 10 L 13.0625 12 L 10.65625 12 L 11.625 10.5625 L 12 10 L 11.625 9.4375 L 10.65625 8 z M 15.46875 8 L 17.84375 8 L 19.1875 10 L 17.84375 12 L 15.46875 12 L 16.4375 10.5625 L 16.8125 10 L 16.4375 9.4375 L 15.46875 8 z M 20.25 8 L 22.65625 8 L 24 10 L 22.65625 12 L 20.25 12 L 21.21875 10.5625 L 21.59375 10 L 21.21875 9.4375 L 20.25 8 z M 25.0625 8 L 27 8 L 27 12 L 25.0625 12 L 26.03125 10.5625 L 26.40625 10 L 26.03125 9.4375 L 25.0625 8 z M 7 9 C 6.4477153 9 6 9.4477153 6 10 C 6 10.552285 6.4477153 11 7 11 C 7.5522847 11 8 10.552285 8 10 C 8 9.4477153 7.5522847 9 7 9 z M 5 14 L 27 14 L 27 24 L 5 24 L 5 14 z"/>
 </svg>

 <!-- Иконка в центре внизу -->
<svg   width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(130 250)" >

 <path fill="crimson" d="M 4 6 L 4 7 L 4 25 L 4 26 L 5 26 L 27 26 L 28 26 L 28 25 L 28 7 L 28 6 L 27 6 L 5 6 L 4 6 z M 6 8 L 26 8 L 26 24 L 6 24 L 6 8 z M 13 10.625 L 13 12.40625 L 13 19.59375 L 13 21.375 L 14.5 20.46875 L 20.5 16.84375 L 21.9375 16 L 20.5 15.15625 L 14.5 11.53125 L 13 10.625 z M 15 14.15625 L 18.09375 16 L 15 17.84375 L 15 14.15625 z"/>
 </svg>
 
  <!-- Иконка нижний левый угол -->
<svg   width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 32 32"  transform="translate(1 250)" >
    <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M 9.5 5 L 9.1875 5.40625 L 8 7 L 4 7 L 3 7 L 3 8 L 3 25 L 3 26 L 4 26 L 28 26 L 29 26 L 29 25 L 29 8 L 29 7 L 28 7 L 27 7 L 27 6 L 21 6 L 21 7 L 20 7 L 18.8125 5.40625 L 18.5 5 L 18 5 L 10 5 L 9.5 5 z M 10.5 7 L 17.5 7 L 18.6875 8.59375 L 19 9 L 19.5 9 L 27 9 L 27 24 L 5 24 L 5 9 L 8.5 9 L 9 9 L 9.3125 8.59375 L 10.5 7 z M 12 8 L 12 10 L 16 10 L 16 8 L 12 8 z M 7 12 L 7 13 L 7 21 L 7 22 L 8 22 L 20 22 L 21 22 L 21 21 L 21 13 L 21 12 L 20 12 L 8 12 L 7 12 z M 24 13 C 23.447715 13 23 13.447715 23 14 C 23 14.552285 23.447715 15 24 15 C 24.552285 15 25 14.552285 25 14 C 25 13.447715 24.552285 13 24 13 z M 9 14 L 19 14 L 19 20 L 9 20 L 9 14 z M 24 16 C 23.447715 16 23 16.447715 23 17 C 23 17.552285 23.447715 18 24 18 C 24.552285 18 25 17.552285 25 17 C 25 16.447715 24.552285 16 24 16 z M 24 19 C 23.447715 19 23 19.447715 23 20 C 23 20.552285 23.447715 21 24 21 C 24.552285 21 25 20.552285 25 20 C 25 19.447715 24.552285 19 24 19 z"/>
</svg>
 </svg>  
 
 </body>
```

*К большому сожалению этот способ работает только в Firefox - (((*

### #5 Вариант работает во всех браузерах, включая IE11

В варианте #4 использовались  в файле SVG вложенные теги `<svg>` и для позиционирования иконок команда `transform="translate(X Y)` Это  очень удобно, так как у каждого вложенного
 тега `<svg viewBox= 0 0 32 32> ....код иконки ... </svg>` есть свой viewBox, который позволяет масштабировать каждую иконку по отдельности, ***но к сожалению viewBox во вложенных тегах `<svg>..</svg>` понимает только Firefox.***

Поэтому в этом варианте используются только групповые теги `<g>`с  командой позиционирования - `transform="translate(X Y)`

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid grey;" >


         <!-- Иконка по центру -->
 <g id="swithCamera" transform="translate(110 100)">
 
 <g >
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M33.9,12.1H14.2L17.6,7c0.4-0.6,1-0.9,1.7-0.9h9.6c0.7,0,1.3,0.3,1.7,0.9L33.9,12.1z"/>
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M14,11H8V9.2C8,8.5,8.5,8,9.2,8h3.6C13.5,8,14,8.5,14,9.2V11z"/>
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M40,42H8c-2.2,0-4-1.8-4-4V14c0-2.2,1.8-4,4-4h32c2.2,0,4,1.8,4,4v24C44,40.2,42.2,42,40,42z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#E8EAF6" d="M34,25c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10c-2.4,0-4.6,0.8-6.3,2.2l1.2,1.6c1.4-1.1,3.1-1.8,5.1-1.8c4.4,0,8,3.6,8,8h-3.5    l4.5,5.6l4.5-5.6H34z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#E8EAF6" d="M29.1,31.2C27.7,32.3,25.9,33,24,33c-4.4,0-8-3.6-8-8h3.5L15,19.4L10.5,25H14c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10    c2.4,0,4.6-0.8,6.3-2.2L29.1,31.2z"/>
 </g>
</g> 
</g>

 <!-- Иконка в Левом верхнем углу -->
<g   transform="translate(1 1)">

    <path  fill="green" d="M 3 5 L 3 27 L 14 27 L 14 25 L 5 25 L 5 7 L 27 7 L 27 15 L 29 16 L 29 5 L 3 5 z M 7 9 L 7 23 L 14 23 L 14.40625 21 L 9 21 L 9 11 L 23 11 L 23 14 L 25 14.3125 L 25 9 L 7 9 z M 24 16 C 19.593567 16 16 19.593567 16 24 C 16 28.406433 19.593567 32 24 32 C 28.406433 32 32 28.406433 32 24 C 32 19.593567 28.406433 16 24 16 z M 24 18 C 27.325553 18 30 20.674447 30 24 C 30 27.325553 27.325553 30 24 30 C 20.674447 30 18 27.325553 18 24 C 18 20.674447 20.674447 18 24 18 z M 23 20 L 23 23 L 20 23 L 20 25 L 23 25 L 23 28 L 25 28 L 25 25 L 28 25 L 28 23 L 25 23 L 25 20 L 23 20 z"/>
 
</g>

<!-- Иконка в вверху по центру -->
<g   transform="translate(120 1)">
 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M 0 8 L 0 9 L 0 23 L 0 24 L 1 24 L 2 24 L 2 25 L 6 25 L 6 24 L 26 24 L 26 25 L 30 25 L 30 24 L 31 24 L 32 24 L 32 23 L 32 9 L 32 8 L 31 8 L 1 8 L 0 8 z M 2 10 L 30 10 L 30 22 L 2 22 L 2 10 z M 23 11 C 20.250421 11 18 13.250421 18 16 C 18 18.749579 20.250421 21 23 21 C 25.749579 21 28 18.749579 28 16 C 28 13.250421 25.749579 11 23 11 z M 4 13 L 4 15 L 6 15 L 6 13 L 4 13 z M 8 13 L 8 15 L 10 15 L 10 13 L 8 13 z M 12 13 L 12 15 L 14 15 L 14 13 L 12 13 z M 23 13 C 24.668699 13 26 14.331301 26 16 C 26 17.668699 24.668699 19 23 19 C 21.331301 19 20 17.668699 20 16 C 20 14.331301 21.331301 13 23 13 z M 4 17 L 4 19 L 6 19 L 6 17 L 4 17 z M 8 17 L 8 19 L 10 19 L 10 17 L 8 17 z M 12 17 L 12 19 L 14 19 L 14 17 L 12 17 z"/> 
 </g>
 
 
 <!-- Иконка в правом верхнем углу -->
<g     transform="translate(260 1)" >
    <path fill="crimson" d="M 3 5 L 3 27 L 14 27 L 14 25 L 5 25 L 5 7 L 27 7 L 27 15 L 29 16 L 29 5 L 3 5 z M 7 9 L 7 23 L 14 23 L 14.40625 21 L 9 21 L 9 11 L 23 11 L 23 14 L 25 14.3125 L 25 9 L 7 9 z M 24 16 C 19.593567 16 16 19.593567 16 24 C 16 28.406433 19.593567 32 24 32 C 28.406433 32 32 28.406433 32 24 C 32 19.593567 28.406433 16 24 16 z M 24 18 C 27.325553 18 30 20.674447 30 24 C 30 27.325553 27.325553 30 24 30 C 20.674447 30 18 27.325553 18 24 C 18 20.674447 20.674447 18 24 18 z M 21.71875 20.28125 L 20.28125 21.71875 L 22.5625 24 L 20.28125 26.28125 L 21.71875 27.71875 L 24 25.4375 L 26.28125 27.71875 L 27.71875 26.28125 L 25.4375 24 L 27.71875 21.71875 L 26.28125 20.28125 L 24 22.5625 L 21.71875 20.28125 z"/>
</g>

<!-- Иконка в правом нижнем углу -->
<g     transform="translate(260 260)" >

 <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M 3 6 L 3 7 L 3 25 L 3 26 L 4 26 L 28 26 L 29 26 L 29 25 L 29 7 L 29 6 L 28 6 L 4 6 L 3 6 z M 5 8 L 8.25 8 L 9.59375 10 L 8.25 12 L 5 12 L 5 8 z M 10.65625 8 L 13.0625 8 L 14.40625 10 L 13.0625 12 L 10.65625 12 L 11.625 10.5625 L 12 10 L 11.625 9.4375 L 10.65625 8 z M 15.46875 8 L 17.84375 8 L 19.1875 10 L 17.84375 12 L 15.46875 12 L 16.4375 10.5625 L 16.8125 10 L 16.4375 9.4375 L 15.46875 8 z M 20.25 8 L 22.65625 8 L 24 10 L 22.65625 12 L 20.25 12 L 21.21875 10.5625 L 21.59375 10 L 21.21875 9.4375 L 20.25 8 z M 25.0625 8 L 27 8 L 27 12 L 25.0625 12 L 26.03125 10.5625 L 26.40625 10 L 26.03125 9.4375 L 25.0625 8 z M 7 9 C 6.4477153 9 6 9.4477153 6 10 C 6 10.552285 6.4477153 11 7 11 C 7.5522847 11 8 10.552285 8 10 C 8 9.4477153 7.5522847 9 7 9 z M 5 14 L 27 14 L 27 24 L 5 24 L 5 14 z"/>
 </g>

 <!-- Иконка в центре внизу -->
<g     transform="translate(120 260)" >

 <path fill="crimson" d="M 4 6 L 4 7 L 4 25 L 4 26 L 5 26 L 27 26 L 28 26 L 28 25 L 28 7 L 28 6 L 27 6 L 5 6 L 4 6 z M 6 8 L 26 8 L 26 24 L 6 24 L 6 8 z M 13 10.625 L 13 12.40625 L 13 19.59375 L 13 21.375 L 14.5 20.46875 L 20.5 16.84375 L 21.9375 16 L 20.5 15.15625 L 14.5 11.53125 L 13 10.625 z M 15 14.15625 L 18.09375 16 L 15 17.84375 L 15 14.15625 z"/>
 </g>
 
  <!-- Иконка нижний левый угол -->
<g     transform="translate(1 260)" >
    <path fill="#5E35B1" d="M 9.5 5 L 9.1875 5.40625 L 8 7 L 4 7 L 3 7 L 3 8 L 3 25 L 3 26 L 4 26 L 28 26 L 29 26 L 29 25 L 29 8 L 29 7 L 28 7 L 27 7 L 27 6 L 21 6 L 21 7 L 20 7 L 18.8125 5.40625 L 18.5 5 L 18 5 L 10 5 L 9.5 5 z M 10.5 7 L 17.5 7 L 18.6875 8.59375 L 19 9 L 19.5 9 L 27 9 L 27 24 L 5 24 L 5 9 L 8.5 9 L 9 9 L 9.3125 8.59375 L 10.5 7 z M 12 8 L 12 10 L 16 10 L 16 8 L 12 8 z M 7 12 L 7 13 L 7 21 L 7 22 L 8 22 L 20 22 L 21 22 L 21 21 L 21 13 L 21 12 L 20 12 L 8 12 L 7 12 z M 24 13 C 23.447715 13 23 13.447715 23 14 C 23 14.552285 23.447715 15 24 15 C 24.552285 15 25 14.552285 25 14 C 25 13.447715 24.552285 13 24 13 z M 9 14 L 19 14 L 19 20 L 9 20 L 9 14 z M 24 16 C 23.447715 16 23 16.447715 23 17 C 23 17.552285 23.447715 18 24 18 C 24.552285 18 25 17.552285 25 17 C 25 16.447715 24.552285 16 24 16 z M 24 19 C 23.447715 19 23 19.447715 23 20 C 23 20.552285 23.447715 21 24 21 C 24.552285 21 25 20.552285 25 20 C 25 19.447715 24.552285 19 24 19 z"/>
</g>
 </svg>
```