# Как сохранить стили элементов, обрезанных с помощью clipPath в svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

Не могу разобраться с одной проблемой.
Я рисую различные элементы : геометрические фигуры, текст и прочее используя svg.
Данные о том какие элементы отрисовывать берутся динамически из БД.
Область в которой отрисовываются элементы должны быть строго ограничена, допустим, 100х100px.
Т.е если какие-то, динамически генерируемые элементы, вылезают за эту область, то они должны просто обрезаться.
В результате поисков в гугле, мной был обнаружен тег clipPath,который решил проблему с обрезанием элементов, выходящих за допустимую область, но был обнаружен следующий недостаток, с которым не удалось справиться:
**Пример:**

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
   <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"/>
      <circle cx="60" cy="55" r="20" fill="blue"/>
      <circle cx="80" cy="90" r="20" fill="green"/>
    </clipPath>
  

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
      clip-path="url(#myClip)"/> -->
</svg>
```

Для простоты примера в заданной области я нарисовал три окружности, закрашенные разными цветами: красными,синим и зеленым, но, при оборачивании элементов тегом clipPath они утратили свои стили и стали просто черными.
**Вопрос заключается в том, как избавиться от этой проблемы и сохранить стили элементов, обернутых тегом clipPath?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, тег использовался не правильно.
Вот верное решение:

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
   <circle cx="60" cy="55" r="20" fill="blue" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
   <circle cx="80" cy="90" r="20" fill="green" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
   
<clipPath id="myClip">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="70" height="70"/>
</clipPath>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Вопрос заключается в том, как избавиться от этой проблемы и сохранить
>   стили элементов, обернутых тегом clipPath?

К сожалению   применять стили к clipPath бесполезно.  Так как clipPath работает как ножницы или пуансон штампа - вырезает из подложки кусочки, в вашем случае кружки и их цвет зависит от цвета подложки то есть - прямоугольника. Если прямоугольник будет красного цвета, то и кружки будут красного цвета.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
   <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"/>
      <circle cx="60" cy="55" r="20" fill="blue"/>
      <circle cx="80" cy="90" r="20" fill="green"/>
    </clipPath>
  

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
      clip-path="url(#myClip)" fill="red"/> 
</svg>
```

Если подложка картинка, то результат будет - вырезанные круги с фрагментами картинки.

Comment: Да, спасибо, к счастью удалось решить проблему самостоятельно т сохранить стили с помощью хака, который я описал выше)

Answer (score 3):

> Область в которой отрисовываются элементы должны быть строго
>   ограничена, допустим, 100х100px. Т.е если какие-то, динамически
>   генерируемые элементы, вылезают за эту область, то они должны просто
>   обрезаться

Прочитал ещё раз ваш вопрос. В первом ответе я зациклился на стилях clip-path и поэтому не обратил должного внимания на эту часть вопроса.

Если вам нужно просто вырезать область 100х100px, то самым простым решением может быть использование <kbd>viewport</kbd> и <kbd>viewBox</kbd>  Более подробно [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid grey"> 

<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red" />
   <circle cx="60" cy="55" r="20" fill="blue" />
   <circle cx="80" cy="90" r="20" fill="green" /> 
</svg>
```

Серая рамка показывает область обрезки - viewBox  Показана для наглядности, если мешает, то удалите из шапки файла - `style="border:1px solid grey"`