# Как можно сделать чтобы линия svg не обрезалась?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть линия и когда ее задаю на 100% то, она обрезается слева. Есть ли свойство у `svg`, чтобы линия нормально обрезалась под углом? То есть мне нужно чтобы линия svg заполнялась на всю ширину, и при этом показывались только полные пунктиры.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  height="12" viewBox="0 0 438 12">
    <path fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M-629.714 1.172s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.275-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.275-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.275-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.251 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.275-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.42 0s2.275-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.908 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.501 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.223 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.252 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.908 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.908 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.908 2.333-6.46 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.872 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79zm8.502 0s2.276-2.637 6.46 0c-5.873 11.275-5.285 9.791-5.285 9.791s-1.91 2.333-6.461 0l5.286-9.79zm8.222 0s2.276-2.637 6.461 0c-5.873 11.275-5.286 9.791-5.286 9.791s-1.909 2.333-6.46 0l5.285-9.79z" opacity=".1"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В svg есть инструмент - `clipPath`, который может вырезать по форме, которую вы зададите, в том числе и под углом обрежет. Но не в этом проблема,- вы сдвинули линию слишком сильно влево и поэтому обрезало изображение по вертикали. В этом случае и  `clipPath` не поможет.
Я посмотрел ваш файл в векторном редакторе и увидел, что вы копировали один и тот же элемент много раз. Код `SVG` поэтому получился очень длинный.
Есть более рациональный способ сделать многочисленные повторения одного и того же элемента.

Это заполнение **паттерном** какой-то фигуры.
Вам нужно заполнить строку высотой 12px? В этом случае вы изготовляете `pattern` и заполняете им прямоугольник `rect` высотой `12px` и длиной, которую выберите.

- Последовательность создания паттерна
  Если геометрическая фигура простая, то можно написать вручную через `circle`, `rect`, `line`
  Более сложные фигуры для паттерна придется создавать в векторных редакторах. 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Из рисунка видно, что фигура занимает квадрат `12х12px`
- создаем паттерн

```html
     <defs >
      <pattern id="rectPat"  x="0" y="0" width="12" height="12"
                 patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <path d="m-629.7 1.2c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0l5.3-9.8zm635.2 0c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0C1.9 7.7 3.7 4.4 5.5 1.2Z" id="path4" style="stroke:none;fill:#000;opacity:0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      </defs>
```

Фигура не видна, так как находится в секции `<defs>` это как-бы склад из которого паттерн может использоваться для заполнения одной фигуры или  нескольких. Более подробно о создании и использовании паттернов [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875) и [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns).

- Заполнение паттерном фигуры
  Правило заполнения паттерном фигуры одинаковое для всех случаев:
  Сначала заполняется первая строка слева-направо, затем вторая строка и т.д 
  В вашем случае это будет одна строка высотой `12px`,- прямоугольник hieght="12px"

*Ниже пример кода:*
Изображение адаптивно к любому размеру дисплея.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 12" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  <defs >
  <pattern id="rectPat"  x="0" y="0" width="12" height="12"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
  <path d="m-629.7 1.2c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0l5.3-9.8zm635.2 0c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0C1.9 7.7 3.7 4.4 5.5 1.2Z"  style="stroke:none;fill:#000;opacity:0.3"/>
  </pattern>
  </defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="12" fill="url(#rectPat)"  />
  </svg>
```

Чтобы линия всегда прижималась к левому краю -

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
```

**Update 15.01.2018**
По комментариям автора вопроса

> белые пробелы получаются шире чем были изначально, можно ли как-то
>   ужать их?

Для уменьшения пробелов, можно попробовать уменьшить ширину паттерна на `1px` `width="11"` Если еще больше уменьшать, то станет заметна подрезка фигуры.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="5%" viewBox="0 0 1200 12" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  
  <defs >
  <pattern id="rectPat"  x="0" y="0" width="11" height="12"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
  <path d="m-629.7 1.2c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0l5.3-9.8zm635.2 0c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0C1.9 7.7 3.7 4.4 5.5 1.2Z"  style="stroke:none;fill:#000;opacity:0.3"/>
  </pattern>
  </defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="12" fill="url(#rectPat)"  />

  </svg>
```

Для более объективной оценки скачайте коды примеров на свой ПК, так как здесь в сниппете, иногда внешний вид несколько отличается от вида в чистом браузере.

**Пример с двумя линиями с паттерном по середине текст**

адаптивность изображения достигается применением процентов вместо фиксированных размеров для прямоугольников и текста.

```html
   


<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="5%" viewBox="0 0 1200 25" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  
  <defs >
  <pattern id="rectPat"  x="0" y="0" width="12" height="12"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
  <path d="m-629.7 1.2c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0l5.3-9.8zm635.2 0c0 0 2.3-2.6 6.5 0-5.9 11.3-5.3 9.8-5.3 9.8 0 0-1.9 2.3-6.5 0C1.9 7.7 3.7 4.4 5.5 1.2Z"  style="stroke:none;fill:#000;opacity:0.3"/>
  </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0 10)">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="40%" height="12" fill="url(#rectPat)"  />
<text x="41%" y="12" font-size="1.5em" font-family="serif" fill="grey">Ваш заголовок текст</text>
<rect x="60%" y="0" width="40%" height="12" fill="url(#rectPat)"  />
</g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: `clipPatch` или `clipPath`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Орлиный глаз! Конечно `clipPath` сейчас исправлю

Comment: @Alexandr_T спасибо за хороший развернутый ответ! Но хотел бы еще 2 момента уточнить: 1) Если делать заполнение паттерном элементом width: 12px то белые пробелы получаются шире чем были изначально, можно ли как-то ужать их? 2) Когда адаптивится ваш пример, то линия пропорционально уменьшается, а можно ли сделать так что высота пунктира оставалась постоянной, а уменьшалось только количество пунктиров

Comment: @Silentium Я брал ваш файл, загонял в inkscape, оставил только один элемент на рисунке в ответе видно. А дальше идет масштабирование. В комментарии у вас width:12px  может height="12px" ?  Вариант, который просите вы будет не адаптивен, так как в svg всё считается пропорционально - изменяете длину, меняется высота. Чтобы высота не менялась её нужно сделать фиксированной, как у вас было в вопросе

Comment: @Silentium добавил в ответ вариант с уменьшением ширины паттерна, что должно уменьшить пробелы между фигурами.  Для получения нужного внешнего вида, как вам надо в итоге, поиграйте со значениями `width` `height` viewBox="0 0 1200 12" в шапке SVG файла  Для понимания, как эти параметры влияют на масштабирование почитайте вот этот пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748   Если ответ вам здесь был полезен, пожалуйста  не забудьте отметить его галочкой