# Как сделать адаптивную координатную сетку

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg

Часто вижу в ответах использование координатной сетки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она используется, как фон для различных элементов. Но эта сетка нарисована видимо в растровом редакторе и сохранена в растровом формате.

На мой взгляд, для адаптивности, видимо нужно сделать координатную сетку в формате SVG.

Рисовать с помощью `line`, `polline`, `path` не вариант.

Попробовал сделать с помощью `pattern`, где каждая ячейка имеет размеры `10Х10px`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
      <pattern id="p10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
      </pattern>
         </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#p10)" />
  </svg>
```

Но как сделать, чтобы были ещё деления через каждые `100px`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант на CSS

Использование абсолютных единиц измерения (`px` - в примере)

```css
body {
  
  --wM: 1px;        /* Толщина линии */
  --xM: 10px;       /* Отступ по ширине */
  --yM: 10px;       /* Отступ по высоте */
  --cM: #ccc;       /* Цвет линии */
  
  --wB: 1px;        /* Толщина линии */
  --xB: 100px;      /* Отступ по ширине */
  --yB: 100px;      /* Отступ по высоте */
  --cB: #333; /* Цвет линии */
  
  background-position: -1px 0;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cB) var(--wB), transparent var(--wB)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cB) var(--wB), transparent var(--wB)),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cM) var(--wM), transparent var(--wM)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cM) var(--wM), transparent var(--wM));
  background-size: 
    var(--xB) 100%, 100% var(--yB),
    var(--xM) 100%, 100% var(--yM);
}

#block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div> <!-- Для примера -->
```

---

Использование относительных единиц измерения (`vw` - в примере)

```css
body {
  
  --wM: 1px;              /* Толщина линии */
  --xM: calc(100vw / 60); /* Отступ по ширине */
  --yM: calc(100vw / 60); /* Отступ по высоте */
  --cM: #ccc;             /* Цвет линии */
  
  --wB: 1px;              /* Толщина линии */
  --xB: calc(100vw / 12); /* Отступ по ширине */
  --yB: calc(100vw / 12); /* Отступ по высоте */
  --cB: #333;             /* Цвет линии */
  
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cB) var(--wB), transparent var(--wB)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cB) var(--wB), transparent var(--wB)),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cM) var(--wM), transparent var(--wM)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cM) var(--wM), transparent var(--wM));
  background-size: 
    var(--xB) 100%, 100% var(--yB),
    var(--xM) 100%, 100% var(--yM);
  
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

Comment: для SVG подойдёт интересно

Comment: @MaximLensky не подойдет. Сетка не адаптивна Автору плюс за попытку

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я так и подумал .. но плюс поставил и тебе и ему ...  обычно пишу SVG с картинки

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, но.. Сетка будет адаптивной, если указать относительные единицы измерения..

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 так укажи пожалуйста, если сетка будет адаптивной, то есть не обрезаться и масштабироваться при изменении размеров окна браузера, то с удовольствием приму ответ.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 по задумке адаптивная сетка полезна при **визуальной оценке**, как будет расположен объект. SVG, есть ли свободные поля вокруг него, которые обычно мешают вёрстке или напротив  обрезается сам объект SVG/  Короче, для решения обычных проблем масштабирования, позиционирования SVG

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 недостатки в новом варианте, наверное ты сам видел.  Сетка хоть и стала в целом адаптивной, но из-за применения линейных градиентов возникают баги  прорисовки линий при изменении размеров окна браузера И где цифры?? Они нужны для разметки. Зачем тогда сетка нужна Я приму ответ авансом раз обещал.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, нет, не стоит принимать ответ.

Answer (score 6):

> Но как сделать, чтобы были ещё деления через каждые 100px?

Можно использовать вложенные [**pattern**](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875) | **[pattern на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)**
Внешний pattern будет иметь размеры `100Х100px`, внутренний pattern`10X10px`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   <defs>
      <pattern id="p10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="p100" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#p10)"/>
        <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#p100)" />
  </svg>
```

- Добавляем цифры с помощью  `<text x="-20" y="100" >100</text>`
- рамку, чтобы было видно границы холста SVG  `style="border:solid">`
- Добавим поверх сетки, SVG изображение, например ракету
- Добавим небольшой скрипт, который позволит изменять ширину SVG

```js
 function changeHight() {
  itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{svg.setAttribute("height",itr.value)});
    var x = document.getElementById("itr").value;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "SVG height: " + x +"px";
}
```

```html
<style>
text {
font-size:20px;
fill:black;
}
p {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
<p id="info" ></p>
<div><input id="itr" type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="1000" oninput="changeHight()"/></div>
 
 <svg id="svg" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="-20 -20 1050 1050" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:3px solid purple">
   <defs> 
    
      <pattern id="p10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="p100" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#p10)"/>
        <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="1000" height="1000" fill="url(#p100)" />
    
      <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="5" fill="black" />
     
     <!-- Вертикальный блок цифр -->

      <text x="-15" y="0">0,0</text> 
       <text x="-20" y="100" >100</text> 
        <text x="-20" y="200">200</text> 
         <text x="-20" y="300">300</text> 
          <text x="-20" y="400">400</text> 
           <text x="-20" y="500">500</text> 
          <text x="-20" y="600">600</text> 
         <text x="-20" y="700">700</text> 
        <text x="-20" y="800">800</text>
       <text x="-20" y="900">900</text> 
      <text x="-20" y="1000">1000</text> 
          <!-- Горизонтальный блок --> 
     <text x="100" y="-5" >100</text> 
       <text x="200" y="-5" >200</text> 
        <text x="300" y="-5">300</text> 
         <text x="400" y="-5">400</text> 
          <text x="500" y="-5">500</text>    
         <text x="600" y="-5">600</text> 
         <text x="700" y="-5">700</text> 
        <text x="800" y="-5">800</text>
       <text x="900" y="-5">900</text>  
      <text x="990" y="-5">1000</text>   
      <!-- Ракета      -->
      <g transform="scale(1)" fill="purple">
      <path  d="m308.167 241.52c0-28.766-23.403-52.169-52.17-52.169s-52.17 23.403-52.17 52.169c0 28.767 23.403 52.17 52.17 52.17s52.17-23.404 52.17-52.17zm-52.169 22.169c-12.225 0-22.17-9.945-22.17-22.17 0-12.224 9.945-22.169 22.17-22.169s22.17 9.945 22.17 22.169c-.001 12.225-9.946 22.17-22.17 22.17z"/>
  <path   d="m425.684 424.352v-132.322l-51.65-32.948c.615-14.332.261-28.762-1.117-43.191-7.162-74.973-41.384-144.771-96.362-196.535l-20.557-19.356-20.558 19.356c-54.978 51.765-89.2 121.563-96.362 196.535-1.378 14.429-1.732 28.859-1.117 43.191l-51.65 32.948v132.321l90.003-28.282c3.744 6.784 7.752 13.436 12.017 19.945v62.315h30v-48.333h22.667v23.252h30v-23.252h22.667v48.333h30v-62.315c4.265-6.508 8.273-13.161 12.017-19.945zm-30-115.874v75.001l-46.66-14.662c10.468-24.35 17.778-49.975 21.762-76.222zm-139.694-267.28c27.301 25.706 48.392 55.971 63.081 88.684h-126.153c14.687-32.713 35.775-62.979 63.072-88.684zm-139.679 342.281v-75.001l24.898-15.883c3.983 26.247 11.293 51.872 21.762 76.222zm124.687-10.983v27.499h-27.316c-47.563-72.299-57.394-161.126-32.242-240.114h149.112c25.156 78.987 15.325 167.815-32.238 240.114h-27.316v-27.499z"/>
   <path  d="m240.998 483.495h30v28.5h-30z"/> 
   </g>
  </svg>
```

***Вариант с возможностью изменять `width` и `height` SVG***

```js
function changeHeight() {
  itrX.addEventListener("input",()=>{svg.setAttribute("height",itrX.value)});
    var x = document.getElementById("itrX").value;
    document.getElementById("infoX").innerHTML = "SVG height: " + x +"px";
}
  function changeWidth() {
  itrY.addEventListener("input",()=>{svg.setAttribute("width",itrY.value)});
    var x = document.getElementById("itrY").value;
    document.getElementById("infoY").innerHTML = "SVG width: " + x +"px";
}
```

```html
<style>
text {
font-size:20px;
fill:black;
}
p {
display:inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
margin: 1em ;
}
</style>
<p id="infoX" ></p>
<p id="infoY" ></p>
<div>
 <span><input id="itrX" type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="1000" oninput="changeHeight()"/></span>
  <span><input id="itrY" type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="1000" oninput="changeWidth()"/></span>
</div>

 
 <svg id="svg" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="-20 -20 1050 1050" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:2px solid purple">
   <defs> 
    
      <pattern id="p10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="p100" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#p10)"/>
        <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="1000" height="1000" fill="url(#p100)" />
    
      <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="5" fill="black" />
      
     <!-- Вертикальный блок цифр -->

      <text x="-15" y="0">0,0</text> 
       <text x="-20" y="100" >100</text> 
        <text x="-20" y="200">200</text> 
         <text x="-20" y="300">300</text> 
          <text x="-20" y="400">400</text> 
           <text x="-20" y="500">500</text> 
          <text x="-20" y="600">600</text> 
         <text x="-20" y="700">700</text> 
        <text x="-20" y="800">800</text>
       <text x="-20" y="900">900</text> 
      <text x="-20" y="1000">1000</text> 
          <!-- Горизонтальный блок --> 
     <text x="100" y="-5" >100</text> 
       <text x="200" y="-5" >200</text> 
        <text x="300" y="-5">300</text> 
         <text x="400" y="-5">400</text> 
          <text x="500" y="-5">500</text>    
         <text x="600" y="-5">600</text> 
         <text x="700" y="-5">700</text> 
        <text x="800" y="-5">800</text>
       <text x="900" y="-5">900</text>  
      <text x="990" y="-5">1000</text>   
      <!-- Ракета      -->
      <g transform="scale(1)" fill="purple">
      <path  d="m308.167 241.52c0-28.766-23.403-52.169-52.17-52.169s-52.17 23.403-52.17 52.169c0 28.767 23.403 52.17 52.17 52.17s52.17-23.404 52.17-52.17zm-52.169 22.169c-12.225 0-22.17-9.945-22.17-22.17 0-12.224 9.945-22.169 22.17-22.169s22.17 9.945 22.17 22.169c-.001 12.225-9.946 22.17-22.17 22.17z"/>
  <path   d="m425.684 424.352v-132.322l-51.65-32.948c.615-14.332.261-28.762-1.117-43.191-7.162-74.973-41.384-144.771-96.362-196.535l-20.557-19.356-20.558 19.356c-54.978 51.765-89.2 121.563-96.362 196.535-1.378 14.429-1.732 28.859-1.117 43.191l-51.65 32.948v132.321l90.003-28.282c3.744 6.784 7.752 13.436 12.017 19.945v62.315h30v-48.333h22.667v23.252h30v-23.252h22.667v48.333h30v-62.315c4.265-6.508 8.273-13.161 12.017-19.945zm-30-115.874v75.001l-46.66-14.662c10.468-24.35 17.778-49.975 21.762-76.222zm-139.694-267.28c27.301 25.706 48.392 55.971 63.081 88.684h-126.153c14.687-32.713 35.775-62.979 63.072-88.684zm-139.679 342.281v-75.001l24.898-15.883c3.983 26.247 11.293 51.872 21.762 76.222zm124.687-10.983v27.499h-27.316c-47.563-72.299-57.394-161.126-32.242-240.114h149.112c25.156 78.987 15.325 167.815-32.238 240.114h-27.316v-27.499z"/>
   <path  d="m240.998 483.495h30v28.5h-30z"/> 
   </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, проще всего это реализовать с помощью линейного градиента, как это уже реализовал @CbIPoK2513, и как ваш покорный слуга планировал это сделать, но опоздал с ответом. Значит, будет другой вариант - с помощью `HTML`, `CSS` и чуть-чуть `JavaScript`. Такую реализацию я называю - "*Кричи караул!*" Почему? Не скажу. Если кто понял почему, то можете написать в комментариях.

```js
document.getElementById('div100').innerHTML = ("<div class='div100'><div class='div10'></div></div>").repeat(100);
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('div10'); for (var i in els) {els[i].innerHTML = ("<div></div>").repeat(100);}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#div100 {
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid gray; border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.div100 {
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  position: relative; width: 100%; padding-top: calc(100% - 1px); border-right: 1px solid gray; border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.div10 {
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  position: absolute; top: -100%; left: 0; width: 100%; padding-top: 100%;
}

.div10>div {width: 100%; padding-top: calc(100% - 1px); border-right: 1px solid lightgray; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}
.div10>div:nth-child(10n+10) {border-right: none;}
.div10>div:nth-child(n+91) {border-bottom: none;}
```

```html
<div id="div100"></div>
```

Следующим шагом добавим:

- цифры для разметки
- рамку, чтобы было видно границы холста

```js
document.getElementById('div100').innerHTML = ("<div class='div100'><div class='div10'></div></div>").repeat(100);
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('div10'); for (var i in els) {els[i].innerHTML = ("<div></div>").repeat(100);}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.pixel {min-width: 1066px; margin: 10px; padding: 30px; border: 3px solid purple;}

#div100 {
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr); position: relative;
  width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid gray; border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.div100 {
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  position: relative; width: 100%; padding-top: calc(100% - 1px); border-right: 1px solid gray; border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.div10 {
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  position: absolute; top: -100%; left: 0; width: 100%; padding-top: 100%;
}

.div10>div {position: relative; width: 100%; padding-top: calc(100% - 1px); border-right: 1px solid lightgray; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}
.div10>div:nth-child(10n+10) {border-right: none;}
.div10>div:nth-child(n+91) {border-bottom: none;}

#div100::after, .div100::before, .div100::after {position: absolute; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: bold; font-family: monospace;}
#div100::after {top: -1rem; left: -0.8rem; content: "0";}
.div100::before {top: -1.1rem; left: calc(100% - 0.2rem);}
.div100::after {bottom: -0.8rem; left: -1.6rem;}
.div100:nth-child(1)::before, .div100:nth-child(1)::after {content: "100";}
.div100:nth-child(2)::before, .div100:nth-child(11)::after {content: "200";}
.div100:nth-child(3)::before, .div100:nth-child(21)::after {content: "300";}
.div100:nth-child(4)::before, .div100:nth-child(31)::after {content: "400";}
.div100:nth-child(5)::before, .div100:nth-child(41)::after {content: "500";}
.div100:nth-child(6)::before, .div100:nth-child(51)::after {content: "600";}
.div100:nth-child(7)::before, .div100:nth-child(61)::after {content: "700";}
.div100:nth-child(8)::before, .div100:nth-child(71)::after {content: "800";}
.div100:nth-child(9)::before, .div100:nth-child(81)::after {content: "900";}
.div100:nth-child(10)::before, .div100:nth-child(91)::after {content: "1000";}
.div100:nth-child(91)::after {left: -1.85rem;}

#div100::before {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 7px); left: calc(50% - 7px); width: 12px; height: 12px; border-radius: 100%; background: black; z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="pixel"><div id="div100"></div></div>
```

---

<sub>**P.S.** *Заинтересовавшись первым вариантом ответа участника @CbIPoK2513, где он создал координатную сетку с помощью технологии CSS, используя абсолютную единицу измерения - пиксель(px), мною был задан [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250647/377637) и приведен [один из вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250648/377637) такого решения.*</sub>

Comment: На мой взгляд ваш вариант более интересен и надежен, чем у CbIPoK2513 Ваши вопросы в ответе закономерны, но присутствует некоторое недопонимание принципов масштабирования и позиционирования в SVG/ Если действительно есть желание разобраться в этих сложнейших вопросах, то можно почитать статью [Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

Comment: Если указаны фиксированные размеры 10px, 100px то это их физические размеры, но при рендеринге они могут быть сжаты, растянуты с помощью `width`, `htight`, `viewBox`  Даже после этих трансформаций они сохранят свои физические размеры (как были нарисованы изначально) Это можно проверить с помощью `getBBox()` Хотя  в окне браузера они могут занимать различное пространство. **Да, ещё нужно добавить цифры к координатной сетке, без них, нет смысла в ней**

Answer (score 2):

Для примера приведу - я обычно использую javascript для генерации сетки и рисую точно по ней...

Выглядит это так

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg#svg"),
  height = svg.getBoundingClientRect().height,
  width = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width,
  html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++)
  html += `<path class="vertical" d="M ${i * 10}, 0  ${i * 10} ${height}" />`;
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  html += `<path class="gorizontal" d="M0,${i * 10} ${width} ${i * 10}" />`;
svg.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg#svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

svg#svg path {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.2px;
}

#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  z-ndex: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 150"></svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <path d="M20,10 30,100" 
        stroke="red"
        stroke-width="1"
        fill="none"/>
  
  <circle cx="200" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Получается что я рисую новый SVG по верх сетки и что бы сетка не мешала самому рисунку я сетку распологаю абсолютно с отрицательным z-index

Вот к примеру я делал некий sin

```js
let width = document.getElementById("svg").getBoundingClientRect().width;
let height = document.getElementById("svg").getBoundingClientRect().height;

let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < width / 5; i++) {
  html += `<path d="M ${i * 10}, 0  ${i * 10} ${height}" />`;
  html += `<path class="gorizontal" d="M0,${i * 10} ${width} ${i * 10}" />`;
}

document.getElementById("svg").innerHTML = html
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300 150"></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <path d="M20,50 
           c0,0 25,25 50,0
           c0,0 25,-25 50,0
           c0,0 25,25 50,0
           c0,0 25,-25 50,0" 
        fill="none"
        stroke="blue"
        stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

Вот так будет выглядеть сетка 5x5

```
let width = document.getElementById("svg").getBoundingClientRect().width;
let height = document.getElementById("svg").getBoundingClientRect().height;
let conf = 5;

let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  html += `<path d="M ${i * conf}, 0  ${i * conf} ${height}" />`;
  html += `<path d="M0,${i * conf} ${width} ${i * conf}" />`;
}

document.getElementById("svg").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: хороший, полезный  ответ

Comment: @Sevastopol' я по такой сетке рисую, удобно...и кода не много