# Координатная (пиксельная) сетка (линейка)

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, координаты

Меня заинтересовала [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250493/377637) участника [@CbIPoK2513](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221218/cbipok2513), где он создал координатную сетку с помощью технологии CSS, используя абсолютную единицу измерения - пиксель(px).

Вот его [первая часть ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250493/377637) на вопрос [Как сделать адаптивную координатную сетку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250323/377637):

```css
body {
  
  --wM: 1px;        /* Толщина линии */
  --xM: 10px;       /* Отступ по ширине */
  --yM: 10px;       /* Отступ по высоте */
  --cM: #ccc;       /* Цвет линии */
  
  --wB: 1px;        /* Толщина линии */
  --xB: 100px;      /* Отступ по ширине */
  --yB: 100px;      /* Отступ по высоте */
  --cB: #333; /* Цвет линии */
  
  background-position: -1px 0;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cB) var(--wB), transparent var(--wB)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cB) var(--wB), transparent var(--wB)),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cM) var(--wM), transparent var(--wM)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cM) var(--wM), transparent var(--wM));
  background-size: 
    var(--xB) 100%, 100% var(--yB),
    var(--xM) 100%, 100% var(--yM);
}

#block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div> <!-- Для примера -->
```

Автор: [@CbIPoK2513](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221218/cbipok2513)

Такая координатная сетка для удобства работы используется как фон (подложка) при отладке и вёрстке различных элементов дизайна web-страниц, а также демонстрации прозрачности этих элементов. Например, участник [@UModeL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265406/umodel) использует в своей работе (ответах) изображение, которое он самостоятельно нарисовал в растровом редакторе. Вот пример такого использования:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png") 0% 0% no-repeat #eee;
}
```

**Вопрос:** Возможны ли иные варианты создать подобную координатную сетку, используя любые другие средства и технологии, указанные в метках вопроса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript + Canvas:

```js
function createBackgroundGrid() {
    let context = document.getElementById("background-grid").getContext("2d");
    const LINE_TYPES = 3;
    const beginPos = [0.5, 50.5, 0.5];
    const step     = [10,  100,  100];
    const style    = ["rgb(210,210,210)", "rgb(150,150,150)", "rgb(0,0,0)"];
    
    function handler() {
        context.canvas.width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        context.canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(245, 245, 245)";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        
        for (let lineType = 0; lineType < LINE_TYPES; ++lineType)
            for (let dir = 0; dir < 2; ++dir) {
                context.beginPath()
                context.strokeStyle = style[lineType];
                let index = beginPos[lineType];
                if (dir == 0)
                    while (index < context.canvas.width) {
                        context.moveTo(index, 0);
                        context.lineTo(index, context.canvas.height);
                        index += step[lineType];
                    }
                else
                    while (index < context.canvas.height) {
                        context.moveTo(0, index);
                        context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, index);
                        index += step[lineType];
                    }
                context.stroke();
            }
        
        const colShift = 5, rowShift = 10;
        
        context.fillStyle = "blue";
        let col = 0;
        while (col + colShift < context.canvas.width) {
            context.fillText(col, col + colShift, 0 + rowShift);
            col += step[step.length - 1];
        }
        
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        let row = 0 + step[step.length - 1];
        while (row + rowShift < context.canvas.height) {
            context.fillText(row, 0 + colShift, row + rowShift);
            row += step[step.length - 1];
        }
    }
    handler();
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => requestAnimationFrame(handler));
}

createBackgroundGrid();
```

```css
#background-grid {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "background-grid"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

Такую координатную сетку я попытался создать с помощью HTML+CSS и JavaScript. Вот, что у меня получилось:

```js
// Ширина окна
document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = window.innerWidth;
// Высота окна
document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = window.innerHeight;

// Ширину окна делим на 10 пикселей (размер ячейки) и получаем количество ячеек по горизонтали
var num_w = innerWidth / 10;
// Высоту окна делим на 10 пикселей (размер ячейки) и получаем количество ячеек по вертикали
var num_h = innerHeight / 10;

// Выводим результаты в консоль
console.log('Ш:',num_w,'~','В:',num_h);

// Выводим общее количество ячеек на экран
document.getElementById('pixel').innerHTML = ("<div class='row'>" + "<div class='cell'></div>".repeat(num_w) + "</div>").repeat(num_h);
```

```css
/*Общие стили*/
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {width: 100%; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}

/*Координатная сетка*/
#pixel {display: table;}
.row {display: table-row; height: 10px;}
.cell {display: table-cell; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 10px; height: 10px;}

/*Окно с размерами*/
.info {position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 0; border: none; background: black; color: white; width: 200px; height: 100px;}
.info p {padding: 7px 7px 0 7px; font-size: 12px; font-family: monospace;}
```

```html
<!--Координатная сетка-->
<div id="pixel"></div>

<!--Окно с размерами-->
<div class="info">
<p>Ширина окна: <b id="width"></b>px</p>
<p>Высота окна: <b id="height"></b>px</p>
<p></p>
<p>Ширина этого блока - <b>200</b>px</p>
<p>Высота этого блока - <b>100</b>px</p>
</div>
```

Однако, у такого решения имеются два минуса:

1. В случае, если ширина окна не кратна десяти, то сетка полностью не заполняет всю его рабочую область (как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали) и не выходит за его пределы, а обрезается, оставляя по правой и нижней сторонам пустое пространство. По всей видимости, необходимо каким-то образом округлять размеры экрана всегда в большую сторону.
2. При изменении (масштабировании, *risize*) размера окна координатная сетка не перерисовывается.

Предлагаю доработать это решение и дать самостоятельный ответ. А также приветствуются любые другие индивидуальные варианты ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Хочу дополнить ответ [@Sevastopol'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250648/221218):

Я бы отметил тут ещё третий минус - каждая ячейка секции это элемент и их много, это нагружает страницу, что но есть хорошо.

---

Так же хочу дополнить, что в данную сетку можно добавить "ориентиры" в виде нумирации, допустим каждого 100го пикселя, средствами CSS:

```js
// Ширину окна делим на 10 пикселей (размер ячейки) и получаем количество ячеек по горизонтали
var num_w = innerWidth / 10;
// Высоту окна делим на 10 пикселей (размер ячейки) и получаем количество ячеек по вертикали
var num_h = innerHeight / 10;

// Выводим общее количество ячеек на экран
document.getElementById('pixel').innerHTML = ("<div class='row'>" + "<div class='cell'></div>".repeat(num_w) + "</div>").repeat(num_h);
```

```css
/*Общие стили*/
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {width: 100%; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}


/*Координатная сетка*/
#pixel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  counter-reset: X, Y;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}


/* "Ориентиры" по высоте */
.row:nth-child(10n+10) {
  counter-increment: Y;
  position: relative;
}

.row:nth-child(10n+10) .cell {
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}

.row:nth-child(10n+10)::before {
  content: counter(Y)'00';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

/* "Ориентиры" по ширине */
.row .cell:nth-child(10n+10) {
  border-right-color: #333;
}

.row:first-child .cell:nth-child(10n+10) {
  counter-increment: X;
  position: relative;
}

.row:first-child .cell:nth-child(10n+10)::before {
  content: counter(X)'00';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* блок для теста */
#test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!--Координатная сетка-->
<div id="pixel"></div>

<!--Блок для теста--->
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

А минус:

> При изменении (масштабировании, risize) размера окна координатная сетка не перерисовывается.

можно и решить:

```js
function Render() {
  var num_w = innerWidth / 10;
  var num_h = innerHeight / 10;

  document.getElementById('pixel').innerHTML = ('<div class="row">'+'<div class="cell"></div>'.repeat(num_w)+'</div>').repeat(num_h);
} Render();

window.addEventListener('resize', Render);
```

```css
/*Общие стили*/
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {width: 100%; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}


/*Координатная сетка*/
#pixel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  counter-reset: X, Y;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}


/* "Ориентиры" по высоте */
.row:nth-child(10n+10) {
  counter-increment: Y;
  position: relative;
}

.row:nth-child(10n+10) .cell {
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}

.row:nth-child(10n+10)::before {
  content: counter(Y)'00';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

/* "Ориентиры" по ширине */
.row .cell:nth-child(10n+10) {
  border-right-color: #333;
}

.row:first-child .cell:nth-child(10n+10) {
  counter-increment: X;
  position: relative;
}

.row:first-child .cell:nth-child(10n+10)::before {
  content: counter(X)'00';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* блок для теста */
#test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!--Координатная сетка-->
<div id="pixel"></div>

<!--Блок для теста--->
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: **Sevastopol'**, спасибо, на галочку не претендую, этот ответ всего лишь дополнение :)

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался. Имеет место быть полезной при размещении блоков некоторых модификаций модов в играх. Как такой код реализовать вне браузера?

Comment: @ТёмТёмыч, тут речь конкретно про веб, если же речь идёт об игровых движках - то там своя координатная плоскость, да и свой подход для реализации, либо такое изначально уже может быть где-то в дев-тулсах движка.