# Inkscape - Разметка по x и y

Tags: svg, inkscape

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом возможно сделать так, чтобы что по x что по y. Отсчет начинался от нуля?

Пытаюсь ровную окружность выполнить по центру, с этим линями и тд. Это жеть...

И возможно ли не задавать Viewbox? Лучше ли с ним или без него, не совсем понимаю его роль...

Comment: Зачем все эти линии? Нельзя просто центр окружности сместить в (0, 0) документа?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо

Comment: @Laukhin Andrey Цитата - ` Нельзя просто центр окружности сместить в (0, 0) документа` В этом случае будет показана только нижняя, правая четверть окружности. Так делают обычно, чтобы спрятать окружность, которая перемещается по кривой до начала анимации `animateMotion`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Я настаиваю, что можно. Вот [пример](https://codepen.io/Raketych/pen/ZErYzXw) трех окружностей из Вашего ответа. Обратите внимание на координаты центров (cx, cy).

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey ну конечно можно и так, спасибо за пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И возможно ли не задавать Viewbox? Лучше ли с ним или без него, не
> совсем понимаю его роль...

**viewBox** задаёт физические размеры SVG холста и выполняет важную роль при масштабировании и без него невозможно добиться адаптивности SVG изображений.

Допустим вы решили создать иконку `48x48px`. Для этого указываете `viewBox="0 0 48 48"`
Вторая задача: сделать минимальные отступы от краев SVG холста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так как координаты центра окружности находятся в центре svg холста, то она будет привязана к левому верхнему углу `(0,0)` SVG холста

Изменение ширины и высоты `width`, `height` изменяют только отображаемый размер, но привязка к верхнему, левому углу остается.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="border:1px solid;">  
<circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="red" />
</svg>  

<svg width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="border:1px solid;">  
<circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="red" />
</svg>     

<svg width="144" height="144" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="border:1px solid;">  
<circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

по уточнениям в комментариях:

Тёмная рамка показывает границы отображаемого SVG холста `style="border:1px solid;"`

У трех иконок размеры пользовательского окна просмотра (viewport)  разные: `width:"48"` ;  `width:"96"` ;  `width:"144"` но физические размеры, заданные  `viewBox="0 0 48 48"` остаются одинаковыми - `48px`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="border:1px solid;">  
<circle id="circ1" cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="red" />
</svg>  

<svg width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="border:1px solid;">  
<circle id="circ2" cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="red" />
</svg>     

<svg width="144" height="144" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="border:1px solid;">  
<circle id="circ3" cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="red"/>
</svg>

<script>
console.log(circ1.getBBox())
console.log(circ2.getBBox())
console.log(circ3.getBBox())
</script>
```

Comment: `viewBox` задает физические размеры? Просто область просмотра условно бесконечного пространствa холста в относительных единицах - читай "в пропорциях".

Comment: @Leonid именно **физические размеры**, это те размеры, как нарисована фигура в векторном редакторе. Это легко проверяется с помощью `getBBox()`. А вот `width ="x"` `height ="y"`  могут быть любыми и вот от них зависит размеры отрендеренного  изображения на дисплее гаджета. Можно их совсем не указывать и тогда фигура займет всё пространство дисплея гаджета, хотя её физические размеры останутся `48 х 48px`, которые заданы `viewBox="0 0 48 48"`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Все же некорректно утверждать, что `viewBox` задает физические размеры, иначе зачем первые два числа? Да и название само за себя говорит. `viewBox` определяет границы окна отображения документа SVG. Благодаря этому, мы и имеем возможность сместить центр окружности в (0, 0), [сместив](https://codepen.io/Raketych/pen/ZErYzXw) при этом границы области просмотра.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, физические размеры определяются в физических единицах, например, см мм дюйм. Здесь же важно лишь соотношение сторон, собственно в этом и есть масштабируемость и векторность. Размеры определяются уже редакторами и браузерами исходя из настроек по умолчанию или значений атрибутов. И viewBox определяет начало отсчета ширины и высоты области просмотра, опять же в условных единицах, которые важны не сами по себе, а в привязке друг к другу. Это может быть и 1мм и 1000км, а потому называть их физическими нельзя.

Comment: @Leonid и Laukhin Andrey где-то вы немного правы, а где-то и немного нет. Тут нужно много писать отвечая на ваши комментарии, но это будет много текста, который не уместится в десятках комментариев. Вот пост, где с картинками, с действующими программами я пытался разобрать [Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)